# Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery

I am trying to open an image / picture in the Gallery built-in app from inside my application.

I have a URI of the picture (the picture is located on the SD card).

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide more test code to ensure that you retrieve the results correctly.

Comment: look at my answer, it is an update to hcpl's code and it works for astro file manager and oi file manager too.

Comment: Someone should update question, "Get/pick an image from Android's...". Current question interprets that I have image and I want to show it via default gallery app.

Comment: @Vikas, seems that you are right. I don't remember what exactly I have tried to accomplish more than a year ago and why all the answers (including the one that I have selected as a solution) actually answer to a different question...

Comment: Actually, I don't know if it is right to change the question completely. There are 36 people who have added the question to their favorites...

Comment: This question has been answered step by step in this tutorial
 [click to view Tutorial][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506301/app-crashes-when-loading-image-from-gallery/30507641#30507641

Answer (score 356, accepted):

This is a complete solution. I've just updated this example code with the information provided in the answer below by @mad. Also check the solution below from @Khobaib explaining how to deal with picasa images.

## Update

I've just reviewed my original answer and created a simple Android Studio project you can checkout from github and import directly on your system.

https://github.com/hanscappelle/SO-2169649

*(note that the multiple file selection still needs work)*

## Single Picture Selection

With support for images from file explorers thanks to user mad.

```
public class BrowsePictureActivity extends Activity {

    // this is the action code we use in our intent, 
    // this way we know we're looking at the response from our own action
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        findViewById(R.id.Button01)
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                        // select a file
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                    }
                });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * helper to retrieve the path of an image URI
     */
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            // just some safety built in 
            if( uri == null ) {
                // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
                return null;
            }
            // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
            // this will only work for images selected from gallery
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if( cursor != null ){
                int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String path = cursor.getString(column_index);
                cursor.close();
                return path;
            }
            // this is our fallback here
            return uri.getPath();
    }

}
```

## Selecting Multiple Pictures

Since someone requested that information in a comment and it's better to have information gathered.

Set an extra parameter `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` on the intent:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

And in the Result handling check for that parameter:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(data.getAction()))
        && Intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
    // retrieve a collection of selected images
    ArrayList<Parcelable> list = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    // iterate over these images
    if( list != null ) {
       for (Parcelable parcel : list) {
         Uri uri = (Uri) parcel;
         // TODO handle the images one by one here
       }
   }
}
```

Note that this is only supported by API level 18+.

Comment: It doesn't work when I use Astro file manager. Any ideas why?

Comment: @hcpl Thank you for answer. Can you please tell me how to get multiple images...?

Comment: small addition for device compatibility:
intent.setType("image/*");
if (android.os.Build.MODEL.startsWith("HTC")) 
  intent.putExtra("folderType", "com.htc.HTCAlbum.ALL_PHOTOS");

Comment: @hcpl...  what if you wanted to drill down into the gallery to a specified directory programatically.  If the app creates a directory that shows in the gallery, can you just take the user directly to that gallery? handling exceptions of course.  I wouldnt want to show the user every directory and have them select, I just want to show them the directory that I want them to be in. You can email me if you want dapiechocki@gmail.com

Comment: I think "selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);" should be "selectedImagePath = selectedImageUri.getPath();".  Then, it compiled and worked for me.

Comment: @hcpl I have provided a solution that supports picasa album's image loading also(picase album is part of Android gallery now). Check my solution.

Comment: @gcl1 the getPath() method is a custom helper, don't forget to add it to your code. It will use a content provider if possible and fall back on the uri.getPath() function if not.

Comment: @Noby check my updated answer, it has some info on how to select multiple images on API level 18 and higher. Before that you'll have to provide your own media browser or look for an open source library.

Comment: @Khobaib Thanks for the update. I've added a pointer in my answer.

Comment: Getting a single picture doesn't seem to be working on the newest Android version 4.4 (KitKat) anymore. The _data column from the query returns a null value.

Comment: @Chsristopher Masser, Any suggested alternative for Kitkat?

Comment: @hcpl  You didn't mean 'Intent.hasExtra', you meant 'data.hasExtra' - assuming data is your Intent parameter in onActivityResult().

Comment: This code is working perfectly preKitkat, but from then there are document providers. In my answer I write about what to do in kitkat.

Comment: I get the onActivityResult before I select an image. When I select an image, I get no onActivityResult at all. Testing on samsung s3. Really annoying.. why do I have this problem and not you?

Comment: @hcpl whats the "action" in if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action))?

Comment: @hcpl trying to pick multiple images .........it return null, java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/1944 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.abs_ind.www.example/com.abs_ind.www.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra action should've been a property on the data (intent) object so use data.getAction() there instead. I'll update code example.

Comment: This question has been answered step by step in this tutorial : 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506301/app-crashes-when-loading-image-from-gallery/30507641#30507641

Comment: The multiple image selector is not working for me. It launches the picker and allows multiple selection, but in onActivityResult, data.getAction() is null, and data.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) is false.

Comment: This answer got the uris from multiple selection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071098/select-multiple-images-from-android-how-to-get-uris

Comment: The "getPath" method in the "Single Picture Selection" way returns null if the user choose a image from the "Recent" option in the gallery (tried in Lollipop), I solved it by directly using the Uri

Comment: As a previous comment also addresses, `Intent.hasExtra` is a mistake in the post and should be updated to `data.hasExtra`.

I tried to edit it to this effect but my edit was rejected; not sure why as the current code wouldn't compile and only serve to confuse people further.

Comment: this worked with me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004658/pick-an-image-from-gallery-in-android-studio

Comment: if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(data.getAction())&& data.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM))  returns FALSE

Comment: the managedQuery is deprecated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714701/deprecated-managedquery-issue

Answer (score 134):

Here is an update to the fine code that hcpl posted. but this works with OI file manager, astro file manager AND the media gallery too (tested). so i guess it will work with every file manager (are there many others than those mentioned?). did some corrections to the code he wrote.

```
public class BrowsePicture extends Activity {

    //YOU CAN EDIT THIS TO WHATEVER YOU WANT
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    //ADDED
    private String filemanagerstring;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                // select a file
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
        });
    }

    //UPDATED
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                //OI FILE Manager
                filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                //MEDIA GALLERY
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                //DEBUG PURPOSE - you can delete this if you want
                if(selectedImagePath!=null)
                    System.out.println(selectedImagePath);
                else System.out.println("selectedImagePath is null");
                if(filemanagerstring!=null)
                    System.out.println(filemanagerstring);
                else System.out.println("filemanagerstring is null");

                //NOW WE HAVE OUR WANTED STRING
                if(selectedImagePath!=null)
                    System.out.println("selectedImagePath is the right one for you!");
                else
                    System.out.println("filemanagerstring is the right one for you!");
            }
        }
    }

    //UPDATED!
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if(cursor!=null)
        {
            //HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            //THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

Comment: How do I retrieve Bitmap image from OI path?

Comment: look at the code. at the lines with the comment //NOW WE HAVE OUR WANTED STRING...this is all you need. then use BitmapFactory class to retrieve a bitmap from a path

Comment: Thanks! You have a good point, never tried other file managers :).

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for this. Im a noobie though, can anyone tell me how to use the selectedImagePath or the other paths and set the image in ImageView?

Comment: I would also like to close the cursor :)

Comment: Could also change `else return null;` in `getPath(Uri uri)` to `return uri.getPath();` and get rid of the first `filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();` check. This way you just make one call to `getPath(Uri)` and get the path back (no matter if it was the Gallery or a file manager that was used).

Comment: onActivityResult is never called in my program :(  I am using tabhosts and have tried putting the onActivityResult() method in my TabActivity, my TabGroup AND my original view Activity that originally called the gallery

Comment: thx a lot. but if i choose gallery as source. it will still show the app choice after i select an image. if i choose the filemanager it works all great

Comment: @mad I have provided a solution that supports picasa album's image loading also(picase album is part of Android gallery now). Check my solution.

Comment: I get onActivityResult before picture is selected and no onActivityResult after picture is selected so it does not work for me on samsung s3.

Comment: managedQuery() is deprecated in API 11, can either use CursorLoader which is a bit overkill for this IMHO, or just use getContentResolver().query() like in Khobaib's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17285119/2048266)

Answer (score 26):

hcpl's methods work perfectly pre-KitKat, but not working with the DocumentsProvider API. For that just simply follow the official Android tutorial for documentproviders: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html -> open a document, Bitmap section.

Simply I used hcpl's code and extended it: if the file with the retrieved path to the image throws exception I call this function:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
             getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
}
```

Tested on Nexus 5.

Comment: Really useful answer, should be used for selecting images from "Photos" app.

Comment: I tried this on both local & server's files, worked for both.

Answer (score 11):

basis with the above code, I reflected the code like below, may be it's more suitable:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String selectedImagePath;
    //1:MEDIA GALLERY --- query from MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null){
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }else{
        selectedImagePath = null;
    }

    if(selectedImagePath == null){
        //2:OI FILE Manager --- call method: uri.getPath()
        selectedImagePath = uri.getPath();
    }
    return selectedImagePath;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I went through the solution from @hcpl & @mad. hcpl's solution supports well for local image in the gallery & mad provided a better solution on top of that - it helps to load OI/Astro/Dropbox image as well. But in my app, while working on **picasa library** that's now integrated in Android Gallery, both solution fail.

I searched & analyzed a bit & eventually have come with a better & elegant solution that overcomes this limitation. Thanks to [**Dimitar Darazhanski**](http://dimitar.me/how-to-get-picasa-images-using-the-image-picker-on-android-devices-running-any-os-version/) for his blog, that helped me in this case, I modified a bit to make it easier to understand. Here is my solution goes -

```
public class BrowsePicture extends Activity {

//YOU CAN EDIT THIS TO WHATEVER YOU WANT
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

private String selectedImagePath;
//ADDED
private String filemanagerstring;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))
    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
            // select a file
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            Log.d("URI VAL", "selectedImageUri = " + selectedImageUri.toString());
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            if(selectedImagePath!=null){         
                // IF LOCAL IMAGE, NO MATTER IF ITS DIRECTLY FROM GALLERY (EXCEPT PICASSA ALBUM),
                // OR OI/ASTRO FILE MANAGER. EVEN DROPBOX IS SUPPORTED BY THIS BECAUSE DROPBOX DOWNLOAD THE IMAGE 
                // IN THIS FORM - file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/...
                System.out.println("local image"); 
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("picasa image!");
                loadPicasaImageFromGallery(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}


// NEW METHOD FOR PICASA IMAGE LOAD
private void loadPicasaImageFromGallery(final Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {  MediaColumns.DATA, MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        if (columnIndex != -1) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                // NEW THREAD BECAUSE NETWORK REQUEST WILL BE MADE THAT WILL BE A LONG PROCESS & BLOCK UI
                // IF CALLED IN UI THREAD 
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                        // THIS IS THE BITMAP IMAGE WE ARE LOOKING FOR.
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}


public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {  MediaColumns.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null) {
        //HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
        //THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    }
    else 
        return uri.getPath();               // FOR OI/ASTRO/Dropbox etc
}
```

Check it & let me know if there's some issue with it. I have tested it & it works well in every case.

Hope this will help everyone.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have an *image* folder in your SD card directory for images only.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// tells your intent to get the contents
// opens the URI for your image directory on your sdcard
intent.setType("file:///sdcard/image/*"); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Then you can decide with what you would like to do with the content back in your activity.

This was an example to retrieve the path name for the image, test this with your code just to make sure you can handle the results coming back. You can change the code as needed to better fit your needs.

```
protected final void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int
                     resultCode, final Intent i) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, i);

  // this matches the request code in the above call
  if (requestCode == 1) {
      Uri _uri = i.getData();

    // this will be null if no image was selected...
    if (_uri != null) {
      // now we get the path to the image file
     cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, null,
                                      null, null, null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
     cursor.close();
     }
   }
```

My advice is to try to get retrieving images working correctly, I think the problem is the content of accessing the images on the sdcard. Take a look at [**Displaying images on sd card**](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html).

If you can get that up and running, probably by the example supplying a correct provider, you should be able to figure out a work-around for your code.

Keep me updated by updating this question with your progress. Good luck

Comment: @Anthony, thank you for your response. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

I get the next error:

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=file:///sdcard/images/* }`

Comment: You need to call `startActivityforResult` and supply an activity. That's what I was referring to about deciding on what to next, my bad.

Comment: It still doesn't work... I check that the folder exists and that there is an image file inside the folder. I call `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);` and still get this error...  This code is located outside the Activity, but I have a reference to the activity and call the `startActivityForResult` method on that reference - maybe this is the reason?

Comment: Nah, shouldnt be the reason, what is `1` that your passing in? Try `IMAGE_PICK`

Comment: The second param is just something for me, isn't it? This is just an int that will be passed back to me together with the result. Tried also the `Intent.ACTION_PICK` instead of `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. What do you mean by `IMAGE_PICK`? There is no such a constant. I also tried `intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/image/")));`. I tried all the possible combinations of these and nothing seems to work...

Comment: yeah `IMAGE_PICK` was a personal constant for another person having problems with Android, I thought it was a constant that choose which image picked, but what happens when you tried to use `intent.setData(...)`, do you get an error message? or nothing happens?

Comment: I get an exception on `startActivityForResult` method call in all the cases (`ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, `ACTION_PICK`, `setType`, `setData`), tried to remove the "file://" prefix, tried to remove the "*" posfix, tried to remove both, tried to give the full path to the file - I've tried all the combinations. Notice that it opens the Gallery app when I don't mention the exact folder or file and use the `setType("image/*");`.

Comment: Does it work for you? Have you tried it? If it does then what platform are you working on? I use the Android 1.5

Comment: I have not tried it, so I couldn't say whether it would work or not and I am using the Android 2.0

Comment: @Michael kessler I just answer a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074270/built-in-gallery-in-specific-folder/8255674#8255674 if it help you in anyway.

Answer (score 10):

this is my revisit to this topic, gathering all the information here, plus from other relevant stack overflow questions. It returns images from some provider, while handling out-of-memory conditions and image rotation. It supports gallery, picasa and file managers, like drop box. Usage is simple: as input, the constructor receives the content resolver and the uri. The output is the final bitmap.

```
/**
 * Creates resized images without exploding memory. Uses the method described in android
 * documentation concerning bitmap allocation, which is to subsample the image to a smaller size,
 * close to some expected size. This is required because the android standard library is unable to
 * create a reduced size image from an image file using memory comparable to the final size (and
 * loading a full sized multi-megapixel picture for processing may exceed application memory budget).
 */

public class UserPicture {
    static int MAX_WIDTH = 600;
    static int MAX_HEIGHT = 800;
    Uri uri;
    ContentResolver resolver;
    String path;
    Matrix orientation;
    int storedHeight;
    int storedWidth;

    public UserPicture(Uri uri, ContentResolver resolver) {
        this.uri = uri;
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    private boolean getInformation() throws IOException {
        if (getInformationFromMediaDatabase())
            return true;

        if (getInformationFromFileSystem())
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    /* Support for gallery apps and remote ("picasa") images */
    private boolean getInformationFromMediaDatabase() {
        String[] fields = { Media.DATA, ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, fields, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null)
            return false;

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA));
        int orientation = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.ORIENTATION));
        this.orientation = new Matrix();
        this.orientation.setRotate(orientation);
        cursor.close();

        return true;
    }

    /* Support for file managers and dropbox */
    private boolean getInformationFromFileSystem() throws IOException {
        path = uri.getPath();

        if (path == null)
            return false;

        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                               ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        this.orientation = new Matrix();
        switch(orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                /* Identity matrix */
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                this.orientation.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                this.orientation.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                this.orientation.setScale(1, -1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                this.orientation.setRotate(90);
                this.orientation.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                this.orientation.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                this.orientation.setRotate(-90);
                this.orientation.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                this.orientation.setRotate(-90);
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean getStoredDimensions() throws IOException {
        InputStream input = resolver.openInputStream(uri);
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(resolver.openInputStream(uri), null, options);

        /* The input stream could be reset instead of closed and reopened if it were possible
           to reliably wrap the input stream on a buffered stream, but it's not possible because
           decodeStream() places an upper read limit of 1024 bytes for a reset to be made (it calls
           mark(1024) on the stream). */
        input.close();

        if (options.outHeight <= 0 || options.outWidth <= 0)
            return false;

        storedHeight = options.outHeight;
        storedWidth = options.outWidth;

        return true;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() throws IOException {
        if (!getInformation())
            throw new FileNotFoundException();

        if (!getStoredDimensions())
            throw new InvalidObjectException(null);

        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, storedWidth, storedHeight);
        orientation.mapRect(rect);
        int width = (int)rect.width();
        int height = (int)rect.height();
        int subSample = 1;

        while (width > MAX_WIDTH || height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width /= 2;
            height /= 2;
            subSample *= 2;
        }

        if (width == 0 || height == 0)
            throw new InvalidObjectException(null);

        Options options = new Options();
        options.inSampleSize = subSample;
        Bitmap subSampled = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(resolver.openInputStream(uri), null, options);

        Bitmap picture;
        if (!orientation.isIdentity()) {
            picture = Bitmap.createBitmap(subSampled, 0, 0, options.outWidth, options.outHeight,
                                          orientation, false);
            subSampled.recycle();
        } else
            picture = subSampled;

        return picture;
    }
}
```

References:

- http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html
- [Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)
- [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/)
- [Set image orientation using ExifInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753912/set-image-orientation-using-exifinterface)
- https://gist.github.com/9re/1990019
- [how to get bitmap information and then decode bitmap from internet-inputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774442/how-to-get-bitmap-information-and-then-decode-bitmap-from-internet-inputstream/)

Answer (score 9):

There are two useful tutorials about image picker with downloadable source code here:

[How to Create Android Image Picker](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-android-image-picker/)

[How to Select and Crop Image on Android](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/)

However, the app will be forced to close sometime, you can fix it by adding android:configChanges attribute into main activity in Manifest file like as:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
```

It seems that the camera API lost control with orientation so this will help it. :)

Answer (score 7):

To display images and videos try this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Wybierz plik"), SELECT_FILE);
```

Answer (score 7):

> Below solution work for 2.3(Gingerbread)-4.4(Kitkat), 5.0(Lollipop) and 6.0(Marshmallow) also:-

**Step 1** Code for opening the gallery to select pics:

```
public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
private void takePictureFromGalleryOrAnyOtherFolder() 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
}
```

**Step 2** Code for getting data in `onActivityResult`:

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    String imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                   //Now you have imagePath do whatever you want to do now
                 }//end of inner if
             }//end of outer if
      }

 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        //Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
                // Will return "image:x*"
                String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(contentUri);
                // Split at colon, use second item in the array
                String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
                // where id is equal to
                String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, sel, new String[] { id }, null);
            } else {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                        projection, null, null, null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String path = null;
        try {
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            path = cursor.getString(column_index).toString();
            cursor.close();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Comment: It's working for me I am using Nexus 5 with Marshmallow. Which phone you are using.

Comment: i m also usng google nexus but faled to get image name or path of my gallery selected image i m  getting null

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=31332, uid=11859 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission() getting this error

Comment: You have add permission which its showing `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: yes i already have added permission in manifest but i did not add any permission in java files at runtime

Comment: This is working if we picked image from recent images from image pick intent. Not working when user picked image from gallery.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case it helps; I do this to get the Bitmap:

```
InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Comment: This is the easiest answer (and the only one that worked for me). So nicely done!

Answer (score 5):

Above Answers are correct. I faced an different issue where in HTC M8 my application crashes when selecting an image from gallery. I'm getting null value for image path. I fixed and optimized with the following solution. in onActivityResult method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
     if (data != null) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = null;
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor imageCursor = mainActivity.getContentResolver().query(
                    selectedImageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            if (imageCursor == null) {
                return;
            }

            imageCursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = imageCursor.getString(columnIndex);
            if (picturePath == null) {
                picturePath = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                String wholeID = DocumentsContract
                        .getDocumentId(selectedImage);

                // Split at colon, use second item in the array
                String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

                String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // where id is equal to
                String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

                Cursor cursor = mainActivity.getContentResolver().query(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        column, sel, new String[] { id }, null);

                columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                }

                cursor.close();
            }
            picturePathAbs = new File(picturePath).getAbsolutePath();
            imageCursor.close();
        }
```

}

Comment: I face similar problem and picturePath is always null . I try you solution but does not work , plus that getDocumentId requires > API 19

Answer (score 3):

```
package com.ImageConvertingDemo;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        EditText tv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        FileInputStream in;
        BufferedInputStream buf;
            try 
            {
                in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/smooth.png");
                buf = new BufferedInputStream(in,1070);
                System.out.println("1.................."+buf);
                byte[] bMapArray= new byte[buf.available()];
                tv.setText(bMapArray.toString());
                buf.read(bMapArray);
                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);

                /*for (int i = 0; i < bMapArray.length; i++) 
                {
                System.out.print("bytearray"+bMapArray[i]);
                }*/
                iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
                //tv.setText(bMapArray.toString());
                //tv.setText(buf.toString());
                if (in != null) 
                {
                    in.close();
                }
                if (buf != null) 
                {
                    buf.close();
                }

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not understand the question before answering. Also, you did not include any description about what you try to do. Also, your code breaks some well established Java programming standards.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class BrowsePictureActivity extends Activity {

    // this is the action code we use in our intent, 
    // this way we know we're looking at the response from our own action
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                        // select a file
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                    }
                });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * helper to retrieve the path of an image URI
     */
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            // just some safety built in 
            if( uri == null ) {
                // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
                return null;
            }
            // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
            // this will only work for images selected from gallery
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if( cursor != null ){
                int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            // this is our fallback here
            return uri.getPath();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

---

#### Retrieve a specific type of file

This example will get a copy of the image.

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_GET = 1;

public void selectImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_GET);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_GET && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = data.getParcelable("data");
        Uri fullPhotoUri = data.getData();
        // Do work with photo saved at fullPhotoUri
        ...
    }
}
```

#### Open a specific type of file

When running on 4.4 or higher, you request to open a file that's managed by another app

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_OPEN = 1;

public void selectImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    // Only the system receives the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, so no need to test.
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_OPEN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_OPEN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri fullPhotoUri = data.getData();
        // Do work with full size photo saved at fullPhotoUri
        ...
    }
}
```

[Original source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Storage)

Answer (score 2):

Additional to previous answers, if you are having problems with getting the right path(like AndroZip) you can use this:

```
  public String getPath(Uri uri ,ContentResolver contentResolver) {
        String[] projection = {  MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
        Cursor cursor;
        try{
            cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        } catch (SecurityException e){
            String path = uri.getPath();
            String result = tryToGetStoragePath(path);
            return  result;
        }
        if(cursor != null) {
            //HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            //THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            return filePath;
        }
        else
            return uri.getPath();               // FOR OI/ASTRO/Dropbox etc
    }

    private String tryToGetStoragePath(String path) {
        int actualPathStart = path.indexOf("//storage");
        String result = path;

        if(actualPathStart!= -1 && actualPathStart< path.length())
            result = path.substring(actualPathStart+1 , path.length());

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Does one need to know the uri of the image here?  What if I just want to pick an arbitrary image from the gallery?

Comment: Intent which you will receive from the gallery will provide you the url

Answer (score 1):

Please find the answer for the selecting single image from gallery

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class PickImage extends Activity {

    Button btnOpen, btnGet, btnPick;
    TextView textInfo1, textInfo2;
    ImageView imageView;

    private static final int RQS_OPEN_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int RQS_GET_IMAGE = 2;
    private static final int RQS_PICK_IMAGE = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_pick);
        btnOpen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open);
        btnGet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.get);
        btnPick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pick);
        textInfo1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info1);
        textInfo2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info2);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(btnOpenOnClickListener);
        btnGet.setOnClickListener(btnGetOnClickListener);
        btnPick.setOnClickListener(btnPickOnClickListener);
    }

    View.OnClickListener btnOpenOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");

            startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_OPEN_IMAGE);
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener btnGetOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");

            startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_OPEN_IMAGE);
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener btnPickOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


            if (requestCode == RQS_OPEN_IMAGE ||
                    requestCode == RQS_GET_IMAGE ||
                    requestCode == RQS_PICK_IMAGE) {

                imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
                textInfo1.setText("");
                textInfo2.setText("");

                Uri mediaUri = data.getData();
                textInfo1.setText(mediaUri.toString());
                String mediaPath = mediaUri.getPath();
                textInfo2.setText(mediaPath);

                //display the image
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mediaUri);
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                   ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a simpler and better solution using the PhotoPicker provided by AndroidDevelopper. You can select one file or multiple files and you can choose the media type.

```
// Registers a photo picker activity launcher in single-select mode.
val pickMedia = registerForActivityResult(PickVisualMedia()) { uri ->
    // Callback is invoked after the user selects a media item or closes the
    // photo picker.
    if (uri != null) {
        Log.d("PhotoPicker", "Selected URI: $uri")
    } else {
        Log.d("PhotoPicker", "No media selected")
    }
}

// Include only one of the following calls to launch(), depending on the types
// of media that you want to let the user choose from.

// Launch the photo picker and let the user choose images and videos.
pickMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia.ImageAndVideo))

// Launch the photo picker and let the user choose only images.
pickMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))

// Launch the photo picker and let the user choose only videos.
pickMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia.VideoOnly))

    // Launch the photo picker and let the user choose only images/videos of a
// specific MIME type, such as GIFs.
val mimeType = "image/gif"
pickMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia.SingleMimeType(mimeType)))
```

And then,

```
// Registers a photo picker activity launcher in multi-select mode.
// In this example, the app lets the user select up to 5 media files.
val pickMultipleMedia =
        registerForActivityResult(PickMultipleVisualMedia(5)) { uris ->
    // Callback is invoked after the user selects media items or closes the
    // photo picker.
    if (uris.isNotEmpty()) {
        Log.d("PhotoPicker", "Number of items selected: ${uris.size}")
    } else {
        Log.d("PhotoPicker", "No media selected")
    }
}
```

You can get more information here [PhotoPicker-AndroidDevelopers](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker)

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way to open image from gallery or camera.

Original reference : ***[get image from gallery in android programmatically](https://demonuts.com/upload-image-camera/)***

Following method will receive image from gallery or camera and will show it in an ImageView. Selected image will be stored internally.

code for xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.exampledemo.parsaniahardik.uploadgalleryimage.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Capture Image and upload to server" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Below image is fetched from server"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/iv"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener{

    private ParseContent parseContent;
    private Button btn;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demonuts_upload_camera";
    private final int CAMERA = 1;
    private AQuery aQuery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        parseContent = new ParseContent(this);
        aQuery = new AQuery(this);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            String path = saveImage(thumbnail);
            try {
                uploadImageToServer(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void uploadImageToServer(final String path) throws IOException, JSONException {

        if (!AndyUtils.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Internet is required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("url", "https://demonuts.com/Demonuts/JsonTest/Tennis/uploadfile.php");
        map.put("filename", path);
        new MultiPartRequester(this, map, CAMERA, this);
        AndyUtils.showSimpleProgressDialog(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(String response, int serviceCode) {
        AndyUtils.removeSimpleProgressDialog();
        Log.d("res", response.toString());
        switch (serviceCode) {

            case CAMERA:
                if (parseContent.isSuccess(response)) {
                    String url = parseContent.getURL(response);
                    aQuery.id(imageview).image(url);
                }
        }
    }

    public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[]{f.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            fo.close();
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my example, might not be as your case exactly.

---

assuming that you get base64 format from your API provider, give it a file name and file extension, save it to certain location in the file system.

```
public static void shownInBuiltInGallery(final Context ctx, String strBase64Image, final String strFileName, final String strFileExtension){

new AsyncTask<String, String, File>() {
    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(String... strBase64Image) {

        Bitmap bmpImage = convertBase64StringToBitmap(strBase64Image[0], Base64.NO_WRAP);

        if(bmpImage == null) {
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }

        byte[] byImage = null;

        if(strFileExtension.compareToIgnoreCase(FILE_EXTENSION_JPG) == 0) {
            byImage = convertToJpgByte(bmpImage); // convert bitmap to binary for latter use
        } else if(strFileExtension.compareToIgnoreCase(FILE_EXTENSION_PNG) == 0){
            byImage = convertToPngByte(bmpImage); // convert bitmap to binary for latter use
        } else if(strFileExtension.compareToIgnoreCase(FILE_EXTENSION_BMP) == 0){
            byImage = convertToBmpByte(bmpImage); // convert bitmap to binary for latter use
        } else {
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }

        if(byImage == null) {
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }

        File imageFolder = ctx.getExternalCacheDir();

        if(imageFolder.exists() == false){
            if(imageFolder.mkdirs() == false){
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        File imageFile = null;

        try {
            imageFile = File.createTempFile(strFileName, strFileExtension, imageFolder);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(imageFile == null){
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }

        if (imageFile.exists() == true) {
            if(imageFile.delete() == false){
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile.getPath());
            fos.write(byImage);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            fos = null;
        }

        return imageFile;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
        super.onPostExecute(file);

            String strAuthority = ctx.getPackageName() + ".provider";
            Uri uriImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx, strAuthority, file);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uriImage, "image/*");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);

    }
}.execute(strBase64Image);}
```

---

Don't forget to set up a proper file provider at first place in AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

---

where the file path is a xml in .../res/xml/file_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<external-files-path name="external_files" path="Accessory"/>

<external-path name="ex_Download" path="Download/" />
<external-path name="ex_Pictures" path="Pictures/" />

<external-files-path name="my_Download" path="Download/" />
<external-files-path name="my_Pictures" path="Pictures/" />
<external-cache-path name="my_cache" path="." />

<files-path name="private_Download" path="Download/" />
<files-path name="private_Pictures" path="Pictures/" />
<cache-path name="private_cache" path="." />
```

---

Long story short, have file provider ready at first, pass Uri to Intent for known and accessible picture source, otherwise, save the picture in desired location and then pass the location (as Uri) to Intent.

Comment: This question has long been answered, and has a few answers that have been repeatedly validated by the community. Why do you prefer this over the existing answers?