# Image, saved to sdcard, doesn't appear in Android's Gallery app

Tags: android, image, save, gallery

I save an image to the sdcard and it doesn't appear in the Gallery application until I pull off the sdcard and return it back.

Do you have any idea why is it so?

Seems like the Gallery application has some cache that isn't updated on file save...

Actually, I also want to open the just-saved image in Gallery application and have no success with that 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically) is my question about this issue.

Comment: This question has been answered step by step in this tutorial
 :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506301/app-crashes-when-loading-image-from-gallery/30507641#30507641

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The system scans the SD card when it is mounted to find any new image (and other) files.  If you are programmatically adding a file, then you can use this class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html

Comment: Side note: Though the question refers to file addition, the MediaScannerConnection doesn't provide a solution for file deletion - not even when requesting to scan the parent folder of a deleted file.

Answer (score 93):

A simpler solution is to use the static convenience method [scanFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29):

```
File imageFile = ...
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { imageFile.getPath() }, new String[] { "image/jpeg" }, null);
```

where `this` is your activity (or whatever context), the mime-type is only necessary if you are using non-standard file extensions and the `null` is for the optional callback (which we don't need for such a simple case).

Comment: Spot on, the broadcast method that others (and google) provide, very rarely works).

Comment: This was working for me in earlier android versions ~4.0 but now in 4.3+ doesn't seem to be working. The images aren't showing up in the gallery app.

Comment: Perfect !
You can get context with : Android.App.Application.Context

Comment: Worked in marshmallow

Comment: Works on Kitkat, works on Pie. The only thing I don't get is why my toast isn't showing in the `OnScanCompletedListener` callback. I invoke `Log.i()` and `Toast.makeText().show()`, but only logging takes effect, there is no toast. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 67):

My answer to the original question and to anyone else that may have this problem:

I was having this same problem, images in my app that people saved to the SD card were not showing up in their Gallery immediately. After some searching I found this one line of code inserted after my 'save to sdcard' code that fixed the problem:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: do we need to use media scanner to be able to use this broadcast? i am using anothermethod to display images in my gallery. When i am using above sendBroadcast on save button click my gallery is not updated with the new image!

Comment: It's old but this may help someone - a more specific path:
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES))));
This method (this answer, not only my comment) doesn't work on the emulator. Test on real device.

Comment: I believe the accepted answer offers the correct way to do it. But if you are trying to support API <= 7 then this is a nice fallback.

Comment: Your answer is helpful for other devices. It's not working on HTC, When I try to scan my Application folder. It doesn't show up newly added image.

Comment: This seems to be no longer supported on Android 4.4 or greater. A permission exception will be thrown in this case.

Comment: this does not work on KITKAT. What is the workaround for this on KITKAT?

Comment: This no longer works !!! Coz android has made this broadcast private with the release of KITKAT . i.e broadcast with intent Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED is protected now.

Answer (score 13):

You can also add an Image to the Media Gallery by intent, have a look at the example code to see how it is done:

```
ContentValues image = new ContentValues();

image.put(Images.Media.TITLE, imageTitle);
image.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, imageDisplayName);
image.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, imageDescription);
image.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, dateTaken);
image.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, dateTaken);
image.put(Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, dateTaken);
image.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
image.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, 0);

 File parent = imageFile.getParentFile();
 String path = parent.toString().toLowerCase();
 String name = parent.getName().toLowerCase();
 image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, path.hashCode());
 image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, name);
 image.put(Images.Media.SIZE, imageFile.length());

 image.put(Images.Media.DATA, imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

 Uri result = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, image);
```

Comment: Hi. This method adds the image to the MediaStore, i have confirmed it by checking the returned `Uri` but the problem is that the inserted image is not showing in the gallery. I have checked both in the beginning and at the end of the gallery. Can you please suggest any method so that the inserted image should show in the gallery immediately?

Answer (score 13):

Gallery refresh including Android KITKAT

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File("file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
} else {
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
}
```

Comment: The code which is inside the first condition whitin "IF" statement works fine for me in KitKat (Android 4.4.4, API 19).

Answer (score 8):

Here is the code for the MediaScannerConnection:

```
MyMediaConnectorClient client = new MyMediaConnectorClient(newfile);
MediaScannerConnection scanner = new MediaScannerConnection(context, client);
client.setScanner(scanner);
scanner.connect();
```

newfile is the File object of your new/saved file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I've already finished this project long time ago... I don't even remember what was the solution that I've used. Other users might find your solution helpful if you'd also provide the implementation of `MyMediaConnectorClient`...

Comment: yes - i'm having real headaches with this at the moment. Please post up :)

Comment: Yes I'm not really clear about how the flow should be -Correct me where I am wrong
I can use MediaScannerConnection to update the SDCAARD info so I take picture with camera and pass the new file into the MSC and now I can access the file with with a connection scanner client?

Comment: The flow is: you take a picture, save it to your sdcard and then make the scanner update, so that the filesystem gets updated to see your saved pic in the device gallery. If you dont do that with the scanner, you see your pic after the next device restart in the gallery.

Answer (score 7):

there is an app in the emulator that says - ' Dev Tools'

click on that and select ' Media Scanning'.. all the images ll get scanned

Comment: great to know, the only way I knew before you said that is to reboot the phone :)

Answer (score 6):

Let your activity implement 'MediaScannerConnectionClient'
and add this to your activity:

```java
private void startScan() {
    if (conn != null) conn.disconnect();
    conn = new MediaScannerConnection(YourActivity.this, YourActivity.this);
    conn.connect();
}

@Override
public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
    try {
        conn.scanFile(yourImagePath, "image/*");
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException e) {}
}

@Override
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    conn.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Hi! What if we know the `Uri` of the image, for example: `content://media/external/images/media/1231778`

Answer (score 6):

this work with me

```
File file = ..... // Save file

context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
```

Answer (score 5):

```java
File folderGIF = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/newgif2"); // path where gif will be stored
boolean success = folderGIF.mkdir(); // make directory
String finalPath = folderGIF + "/test1.gif"; // path of file
.....
/* changes in gallery app if any changes in done*/
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[] {
                        finalPath
                    }, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I want to save animated gif file which is located in external storage and I have the path i.e. /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<PackageName>/files/<FolderName>/xyz.gif. Now I want to Save/copy this file to Image Gallery and show there. How to do this.

Answer (score 4):

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Does not seem to work on KITKAT. **It throws permission denial exception** and crashes the app.
So for this, I have done the following,

```
String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_Some_name.jpg";
CameraActivity.this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                             Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri
                            .parse("file://" + path)));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here I am sharing code that can load an image in the form of a bitmap and save that image on sdcard gallery in app name folder.
You should follow these steps:

1. Download Image Bitmap first

```java
 private Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
     try {
         InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
         return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return null;
 }
```

2. Please also provide following permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```xml
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

3. Here is the whole code that is written for Activity in which we want to perform this task.

```java
void saveMyImage(String appName, String imageUrl, String imageName) {
    Bitmap bmImg = loadBitmap(imageUrl);
    File filename;
    try {
        String path1 = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File file = new File(path1 + "/" + appName);
        if (!file.exists())
            file.mkdirs();
        filename = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageName +
            ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        bmImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        ContentValues image = new ContentValues();
        image.put(Images.Media.TITLE, appName);
        image.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, imageName);
        image.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "App Image");
        image.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        image.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
        image.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, 0);
        File parent = filename.getParentFile();
        image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, parent.toString()
            .toLowerCase().hashCode());
        image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, parent.getName()
            .toLowerCase());
        image.put(Images.Media.SIZE, filename.length());
        image.put(Images.Media.DATA, filename.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri result = getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, image);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "File is Saved in  " + filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope that it can solve your whole problem.

Answer (score 2):

My code for MyMediaConnectorClient:

```
public class MyMediaConnectorClient implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

    String _fisier;
    MediaScannerConnection MEDIA_SCANNER_CONNECTION;

    public MyMediaConnectorClient(String nume) {
        _fisier = nume;
    }

    public void setScanner(MediaScannerConnection msc){
        MEDIA_SCANNER_CONNECTION = msc;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        MEDIA_SCANNER_CONNECTION.scanFile(_fisier, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        if(path.equals(_fisier))
            MEDIA_SCANNER_CONNECTION.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this after saving the image

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: This works but it's not the best solution. You are tricking the system into thinking the SD card would be (re-)mounted and possibly forcing rescanning the whole SD card. MediaScanner.scanFile(..) is the best solution when you now the file you want to add.

Comment: This search for all the images. And it involves a lot of unnecessary data processing that may be irrelevant when we have just single image to be shown up in gallery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permissions to the Gallery app.
Just long press the gallery app icon in the home screen and tap on 'APP INFO' that pops up at the top of the screen. Doing it will show the gallery app settings. Now go in Permissions tab and enable the storage, camera permissions by toggling it.
Now go to your native gallery app and you will get the your saved images.

Answer (score 0):

This will also solve your problem if your image isn't showing in Gallery. Instead, they might show a 404 type bitmap in the middle.
Please replace the tags that are in my code with those of your image because there must be some metadata in order to show an image in Gallery.

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String resultPath = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) +
        getString(R.string.directory) + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

    File file = new File(resultPath);
    file.getParentFile().mkdir();

    try {
        OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(resultPath);
        savedBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    savedBitmap.recycle();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Photo");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Edited");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, file.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US).hashCode());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, file.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.US));
    values.put("_data", resultPath);

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    return resultPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it will broadcast about a new image created, so your image becomes visible inside Gallery.

Replace **photoFile** with the actual file path of the newly created image.

```java
private void galleryAddPicBroadCast() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```