# How to register an image so that it is immediately viewable from Gallery application?

Tags: android

My app creates picture files on external storage (/sdcard). I want those images to be viewable from Gallery (not to open them in Gallery, just make viewable if user switches to Gallery). Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);` to get the path to the public images directory.

I have never tried to do so, but documentation says that that is the place where the public images (thus the gallery) are located.

Source: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29)

EDIT: to notify the gallery DB that another file has been inserted, you might try the following:

```
private void addImageGallery( File file ) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9096984/998759

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do put images there by default, and they become visible, but only after device reboot. However, I want to keep the path customizeable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like charm! I've tried something similar before to no avail, but my code had a mistake, as I can see now :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to use the [MediaScannerConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jens. Use MediaScannerConnection, particularly the static [scanFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) method. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19794372/249239).