# Showing ImageView using BitmapFactory and file path, returns NullPointerException

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, bitmapfactory

UPDATE2: The problem has to do with `onResume` and `onPause`. It has nothing to do with the `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`. The problem is that when I go to take the picture, `onPause` is called, but nothing is saved to `SharedPreferences`, since there is not yet anything to be saved. But once I return from taking the picture, `onResume` is called and attempts to set the image path to the custom object by taking the appropriate value from `SharedPreferences`. Since there is no corresponding value there, it applies the default value of null to `imagePath`.

UPDATE: The layout of my program is `ActivityA` hosts `FragmentA` which hosts this `DialogFragment` you see below. The user presses a button in `FragmentA` to take a picture, and once they have taken the picture, in `onActivityResult` I set the image path as a String variable in a custom object, and I verify it exists by calling `Log.d(mObject.getImagePath(), ...)`.

They can then re-press the same picture button to view the image. This is where the `NullPointerException` occurs. Although I verify that the image path exists in `onActivityResult`, it returns null later when I try to access it. This is why the `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` returns null- since `imagePath` is null in `FragmentA`, of course it will be null when I try to access it as an extra in `DialogFragment`.

Can anyone see why the image path is returning null, even when I verify it exists in `onActivityResult` and assign it to my object? I have no idea why this happens. I have a similar button where a user can input text, and then press the button again to view/edit that text in a dialog. I follow the same procedure of assigning the variable to my object in `onActivityResult`, and I have no problems.

NOTE: If you would like to see how the picture is taken and saved, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26225233/3558874) answer, or follow the linked question to the right.

`imagePath`:

`/data/data/myPackageName/files/myInternalPicturesDir/IMG_20141011_152840.jpg`.

`FragmentA`:

```
    //onCreateView
    mImageButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (isImageButtonFirstClick)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                imageUri = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(CameraUtils.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.d("mImageButton onClick", mMyObject.getImagePath());
                    //returns null...
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                InputImageFragment dialog = InputImageFragment.newInstance(mMyObject.getImagePath());
                dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_IMAGE);
            }
        }
    });

...

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        return;
    }
    ...
    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE)
    {
        String pathToInternallyStoredImage = CameraUtils.saveToInternalStorage(getActivity(), imageUri);
        mMyObject.setImagePath(pathToInternallyStoredImage);

        //verify imagePath exists, both return correct path
        Log.d("onActivityResult pathToInternallyStoredImage", pathToInternallyStoredImage);
        Log.d("onActivityResult mMyObject.getImagePath", mMyObject.getImagePath());

        isImageButtonFirstClick = false;
        preferences.edit().putBoolean("isImageButtonFirstClick", isImageButtonFirstClick).commit();
    }
```

`DialogFragment`:

```
public static InputImageFragment newInstance(String imagePath)
{
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(EXTRA_IMAGEPATH, imagePath);

    InputImageFragment fragment = new InputImageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    String imagePath = (String) getArguments.getSerializable(EXTRA_IMAGEPATH);

    try
    {
        Log.d("onCreateDialog imagePath", imagePath);
        //returns null...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_input_image, null);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogInputImageView);
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(v)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .create();
}
```

}

This returns a `NullPointerException`, and from my reading on `BitmapFactory`, it's either because the file name is null or cannot be decoded into a bitmap.

`10-13 17:10:39.498    5330-5330/myPackageName E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException`

The dialog is shown, but it is just an empty box with an`OK` button.

I've read of similar problems, where the issue was that the `ImageView` itself was null. I don't think this is the problem here, but below is the XML `dialog_input_image`. I've tried tinkering around with the XML, and I've had the `ImageView` as the child of a `FrameLayout` similar to other examples I've seen, but I get the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialogInputImageView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageView>
```

I'm new to Android so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: where u `inflating` the layout in `onCreateView`

Comment: @kaushik Since this is a `DialogFragment` I don't call `onCreateView`. I inflate the layout in `onCreateDialog` then call `setView(v)` when I am returning a new `AlertDialog.Builder`

Comment: Is the Bitmap returned by BitmapFactory.decodeFile null?  Attaching the logcat for this exception would definitely help.

Comment: As far as I can see, the problem is potentially here: `String imagePath = (String) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_IMAGEPATH);`: 1) Where and how are you passing the image path to the fragment? 2) If that is a simple path (String), why are you using `Serializable`?

Comment: @MichaelKrause The logcat shows only that single line when I it calls `decodeFile`.
@shoerat Please see the main post, I've added more code.

Comment: @pez, please change `args.putSerializable(EXTRA_IMAGEPATH, imagePath);` to `args.putString(EXTRA_IMAGEPATH, imagePath);`. Also, change `String imagePath = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_IMAGEPATH);` to `String imagePath = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_IMAGEPATH, "abraka-dabra");` and log `imagePath` in next line. See if you are getting the correct path.

Comment: @shoerat I just remembered why I used `get/putSerializable` instead of `get/putString`. `getString` requires API level 12 and my current min API level is 8. Is there a work-around?

Comment: @pez : no its not it is supported from api lvl 1 [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putString)

Comment: @kaushik I can call `getString(String key)` without an error, but calling `getString(String key, String defaultKey)` gives me the API error in Android Studio.

Comment: @pez, probably you should pass the path here: `dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_IMAGE);`. You seem to be not using the `DIALOG_IMAGE` tag anyway anywhere. You may consider passing the path as a tag and retrieve it using `getTag()` method.

Comment: + you don't really have to use `getString(String key, String defaultKey)`, it was just a suggestion and only needed to see if you are really getting the correct path.

Comment: @shoerat I don't think the path is being saved correctly, even though I use `setImagePath` and verify its existence in `onActivityResult`. I'm not sure why it returns null later when I try to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`.

The problem was that when the user goes to take the picture, `onPause` is called. It checks if there is an existing image path, and if so, saves it to `SharedPreferences`. The first time the user opens the app, no image path will exist so nothing is saved. After the picture is taken, `onResume` is called and attempts to retreive an image path from `SharedPreferences`, but ended up assigning the default value of `null` since no image path existed. I had been using a `boolean` to keep track of when to retreive the information in `onResume`, but a much better solution was simply to check if the value was `null` before attempting to retrieve it.

```
    if (preferences.getString("imagePath", null) != null)
    {
        myObject.setImagePath(preferences.getString("imagePath", null));
    }
```

The original code would have worked, assuming an image path already existed. But it wouldn't have worked the first time.

I apologize for the confusion, and thank you to everyone who tried to help. Although the problem was something unrelated to your answers (and that was my fault), your answers were still helpful and I will implement them as I continue to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use the `Context` method `getFilesDir()` to read from your internal storage, like :

```
String image path = getFilesDir() .getAbsolutePath(); + "/myInternalPicturesDir/IMG_20141011_152840.jpg";
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogInputImageView);
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Calling `getActivity().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();` from my `DialogFragment` simply returns `/data/data/myPackageName/files`. Wouldn't the resulting `imagePath` `String` still be the same?

Comment: Could you past the full stack trace in your post ?

Comment: Sure. This is all it shows: `10-11 16:35:56.098  31000-31000/myPackageName E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Nope, it's just the one line every time I get the error. The only other things that show up around it are my own `Log.d` messages.

Comment: myInternalPicturesDir has been created by your app ?

Comment: Yes, you can see the code for the `CameraUtils` class and how it is called [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26225233/3558874) if you think it would help.

Comment: What does `new File(imagePath).exists();` give ?

Comment: Calling that in `onActivityResult` returns `true`

Comment: Maybe your file is too big or something. If you set up a try catch between decodeFile and print the stack trace, maybe some usefull information will come

Comment: I've tried putting the `decodeFile` and `setImage` parts in a try/catch, but the stacktrace is still the same one line. Strange

Comment: Try this : BitmapFactory.options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); options.inSampleSize = 2; Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think the problem is the filesize, but that didn't work either. The stacktrace is still the same also.

Answer (score 0):

Before changing your Uri to bitmap first get its path from code below and then set it

```
..........
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getRealPathFromURI(URI));
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) throws Exception {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { 
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```