# In Unity3D create a Screenshot button and it can show at the phone Gallery

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

Its working and its saved in my phone...  but the images doesn't show at Gallery.. anyone can help me out?

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + screenShotName + Time.frameCount + ".png", screenshot.EncodeToPNG());
```

So how do I set the path? Main purpose is need can show at Gallery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I refresh the Gallery after I inserted an Image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144840/how-can-i-refresh-the-gallery-after-i-inserted-an-image-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You need the FileSystem to rescan. You can verify this will work, when you reboot your phone and it's there. Filemanagers (not gallerys) usually find the files anyway.

How to rescan is described here: 
[How can I refresh the Gallery after I inserted an Image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144840/how-can-i-refresh-the-gallery-after-i-inserted-an-image-in-android)