# Android How to use MediaScannerConnection scanFile

Tags: android

Im adding images to a folder on the SDCARD.
Since the images and my folder is not immediately visible in the Gallery im
trying to get the MediaScannerConnection to update and show the
folder/images in the gallery.
This is not working so good for me since nothing shows up in Gallery.
Im only testing in Eclipse AVD.

I dont see much talk about this maybe because the scanFile is new since api8.
Could someone show how this is done?

Im trying it in both a service and Activity but keep getting 
uri=null when onScanCompleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image, saved to sdcard, doesn't appear in Android's Gallery app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170214/image-saved-to-sdcard-doesnt-appear-in-androids-gallery-app)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: oh was there an Intent to do this.
Is this also API8?.
Thank you!

Comment: not working really 
    Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/PTPPservice/IMAG1175.jpg")
Or is it a waiting time if scanner is busy?

Comment: I got it working now, wanted to update and show one picture only not the hole SD Card. Thinking it would take long time to re-mount the SD if there is much on it. 
Is there a way to only update a single item?

Comment: This is old but it may be of help to someone - a more specified path:
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES))));

Comment: Actually with Android 4.4 you will even get a java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED for trying this. Using MediaScannerConnection.scanFile is the right way to go. See example in one of the other answers .

Comment: From API 19, application needs system privilege to send ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED intent

Comment: Do not do this anymore for: 1. Not working on almost every current devices. 2. Api < 8 no need to be supported now. 3. **Huge waste for only coding-time convenience**.

Comment: deprecated method

Answer (score 109):

I realized that perhaps you were looking for a solution what would work previous to api level 8, and I could not make sense of Mitch's answer. I solved it by building a class for scanning a single file:

```
import java.io.File;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient;
import android.net.Uri;

public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

    private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
    private File mFile;

    public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
        mFile = f;
        mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
        mMs.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        mMs.disconnect();
    }

}
```

and you would use it like this to make the `MediaScannerConnection` scan a single file:

```
new SingleMediaScanner(this, file);
```

Comment: the media scanner connects then sits there, how long is this supposed  to take?

Comment: @Petrus this works fine. Thanks. But I got an issue. In my application I capture series of images. But finally show only the second image after the scan completed. Can you please tell me what could be the problem.

Comment: May I know why we need to initialize a new MediaScannerConnection, connect it, do the scanFile and then disconnect it everytime? I tried directly using the static method call MediaScannerConnection.scanFile and it works without doing all these.. Update: OK I've asked too early, so the static method only available for API > 8 , thanks!

Comment: also working fine on Android 6 Marshmallow. Thank you.

Comment: Helpful solution!

Answer (score 84):

I was looking for the same thing and I found this in the ApiDemos, ExternalStorage. Solved all my problems as it scans a single file.

```
 MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
          new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
          new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
          Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
          Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
      }
 });
```

Comment: exists only since API level 8

Comment: Best solution to add a single file.

Comment: Works like a charm, for multiple files manually add file paths to the string array

Comment: this works like a charm, does this work for KitKat and above? I don't have a Kitkat device so I couldn't test it myself.

Comment: Bashing my head to wall for 2 days to get this work on kitkat and it didn't. You can try this out on an emulator running kitkat. let me know if it worked.

Comment: @Pedram did you find out a way to make it run on kitkat?

Comment: @Samidh T actually it's working on kitkat but my situation was tricky. I was renaming a bunch of photos. Adding photos and videos is as simple as above code.

Comment: Works like a spell

Comment: Working for API 24 as well!

Comment: Uri is not null and showing path but image won't appear in gallery on emulator in Android 7.1 API 25

Comment: On API<=29, if you set a mimeType array, it must have the same size as the path array. See: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android10-release:frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.java;l=215
On API>=30, mimetype doesn't seem considered. See: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android11-release:frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.java;l=181

Answer (score 30):

Or you can use following method:

```
private void scanFile(String path) {

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this,
                new String[] { path }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "Finished scanning " + path);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Call file scan as:

```
scanFile(yourFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Very nice. simple and easy to implement and worked for me on 4.4

Comment: not working in 4.4.4.. even not getting any error..! is there any permission req. in manifest ?

Comment: Works nicely on 4.4.2

Comment: Currently using 4.4.2 and it does not work (single file, simple situation). Anybody knows why the behavior of this method is so unstable it seems to work only in half of the cases?

Comment: Worked on my Lollipop

Comment: Uri is not null and showing path but image won't appear in gallery on emulator in Android 7.1

Comment: `uri`  is `null` in Android API 32. It seems scanning failed.

Answer (score 11):

Do not do the sendBroadcast if you only want one image to appear in the gallery. That'd be a huge waste of resources.  You'll need to make a MediaScannerConnectionClient and then call connect() on the MediaScannerConnection you make from it to scan the file.
Here's an example:

```
private MediaScannerConnectionClient mediaScannerConnectionClient = 
    new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mediaScannerConnection.scanFile("pathToImage/someImage.jpg", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        if(path.equals("pathToImage/someImage.jpg"))
            mediaScannerConnection.disconnect();
    }
};
new MediaScannerConnection(context, mediaScannerConnectionClient).connect();
```

Comment: what is MEDIA_SCANNER_CONNECTION?

Answer (score 5):

Let your activity implement 'MediaScannerConnectionClient'
and add this to your activity:

```
private void startScan() 
{ 
    if(conn!=null) conn.disconnect();  
    conn = new MediaScannerConnection(YourActivity.this,YourActivity.this); 
    conn.connect(); 
} 

@Override 
public void onMediaScannerConnected() { 
    try{
        conn.scanFile(yourImagePath, "image/*");
       } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException e){
       }
}

@Override 
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) { 
    conn.disconnect(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(absolutePath);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent` instead of `MediaScannerConnection`. `MediaScannerConnection` will make your app gc error with `IMediaScannerListener.Stub mListener`.

```
Intent mediaScannerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
Uri fileContentUri = Uri.parseFile(permFile); // With 'permFile' being the File object
mediaScannerIntent.setData(fileContentUri);
sendBroadcast(mediaScannerIntent);
```