# android create photo album

Tags: android, photo, albumart

do you know how to create a folder in which photos will be saved and os and other apps should see that folder as photo album? I need to save photos in a certain album and if album does not exists, I need to create it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store images files *anywhere* on the external storage (with the exception of locations that also contain a .nomedia file), the media scanner, and thus the built-in "Gallery" app, will locate them and display them.

To be a good citizen you *should* place such files in the recommended location on the external storage using [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29). You can pass that [DIRECTORY_PICTURES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_PICTURES) for images.

Be advised though, that stuff is only available as of API level 8. If you need to also support earlier API versions you can use [getExternalStorageDirectory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) and still use the correct recommended path on your own.

And, as always, you need to [make sure the external storage is available](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) before you try to write to it.

Comment: it seems to work, but when I take some photos and save them in that folder, I can't see then until I restart my device. Is a way to notify the os that I've savem some photos in that folder?

Comment: Yes, any time you want to you can kick off the "media scanner."  Programatically you can use the MediaScannerConnection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile. It always gets restarted when you reboot, so that's why it works then.  (You can also find the "Media Storage" app under Settings->Applications and "Clear data," but that may clear more than you want, like ringtones, album covers, etc.)