# How to extract the file name from URI returned from Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Tags: android

I am using 3rd party file manager to pick a file (PDF in my case) from the file system.

**This is how I launch the activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType(getString(R.string.app_pdf_mime_type));
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

String chooserName = getString(R.string.Browse);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, chooserName);

startActivityForResult(chooser, ActivityRequests.BROWSE);
```

**This is what I have in `onActivityResult`:**

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
if (uri != null) {
    if (uri.toString().startsWith("file:")) {
        fileName = uri.getPath();
    } else { // uri.startsWith("content:")

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

            int id = c.getColumnIndex(Images.Media.DATA);
            if (id != -1) {
                fileName = c.getString(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code snippet is borrowed from *Open Intents File Manager* instructions available here:
http://www.openintents.org/en/node/829

The purpose of `if-else` is backwards compatibility. I wonder if this is a best way to get the file name as I have found that other file managers return all kind of things.
 

For example, *Documents ToGo* return something like the following:

```
content://com.dataviz.dxtg.documentprovider/document/file%3A%2F%2F%2Fsdcard%2Fdropbox%2FTransfer%2Fconsent.pdf
```

on which `getContentResolver().query()` returns `null`.

To make things more interesting, unnamed file manager (I got this URI from client log) returned something like:

```
/./sdcard/downloads/.bin
```

**Is there a preferred way of extracting the file name from URI or one should resort to string parsing?**

Comment: Same question with maybe better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646246/uri-from-intent-action-get-content-into-file

Answer (score 228):

developer.android.com has nice example code for this:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

A condensed version to just extract the file name (assuming "this" is an Activity):

```
public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
  String result = null;
  if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
      if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
      }
    } finally {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
  if (result == null) {
    result = uri.getPath();
    int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (cut != -1) {
      result = result.substring(cut + 1);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: in case when you attempt read mimeType or fileName of file from camera, firstly you have to notify MediaScanner that will convert **URI** of your just created file from `file://` to `content://` in `onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)` method https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815005/2163045

Comment: Adding `new String[]{OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}` as a second parameter to query will filter the columns for a more efficient request.

Comment: `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` didn't work for me, i used `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE` instead.

Comment: This will crash for videos when creating the cursor with a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column latitude` unfortunately. Works perfectly for photos though!

Comment: In your fallback, you could simply call `uri.getLastPathSegment()` instead of parsing it yourself.

Comment: this work only for some apps, not at Files at Android 8

Comment: @JosefVancura have you find any solution? OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME is working on a few phones.

Comment: Does the result contains name including file extension or excluding it?

Comment: Much thanks for this old post. It's 2022 and this still works.

```

Answer (score 58):

Taken from [Retrieving File information | Android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info.html)

#### Retrieving a File's name.

```
private String queryName(ContentResolver resolver, Uri uri) {
    Cursor returnCursor =
            resolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    assert returnCursor != null;
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
    returnCursor.close();
    return name;
}
```

Comment: I've been looking for this for way too long!

Comment: Thank you. Good lord why do they have to make such a trivial thing so annoying?

Comment: It only works with content files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005243/6325722 for full method

Comment: may simplify calling -- queryName( getContentResolver(), uri) ; in MainActivity

Answer (score 49):

I'm using something like this:

```
String scheme = uri.getScheme();
if (scheme.equals("file")) {
    fileName = uri.getLastPathSegment();
}
else if (scheme.equals("content")) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        fileName = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have run some tests on your code. On URI returned by OI File Manager IllegalArgumentException is thrown as column 'title' does not exist. On URI returened by Documents ToGo cursor is null. On URI returned by unknown file manager scheme is (obviously) null.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Yeah, testing for scheme != null is a good idea.  Actually I don't think TITLE is what you want.  I was using that because certain media types in Android (like songs chosen through the music picker) have URIs like content://media/external/audio/media/78 and I wanted to display something more relevant than the ID number.  You can simply use uri.getLastPathSegment() like my code uses for file:// URIs if you have a URI like content://...somefile.pdf

Comment: uri.getLastPathSegment(); - you have saved my day :)

Comment: @Ken Fehling: This didn't work for me. It works when I click a file in a file browser, but when I click on an email attachment, I still get the content://... thing. I tried all the suggestions here without luck. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi, why the `cursor` is not `close()`d?

Comment: Get the uri and use the function getLastPathSegment() to get the file name.
`uri.getLastPathSegment()`

Comment: I think that only MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME and MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE are guaranteed to exist for content:// Uris. See [OpenableColumns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/OpenableColumns.html). If there's a reliable way to know what columns are available for any given Content:// Uri, I haven't found it.

Answer (score 33):

For Kotlin you can use something like this:

```
fun Context.getFileName(uri: Uri): String? = when(uri.scheme) {
    ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT -> getContentFileName(uri)
    else -> uri.path?.let(::File)?.name
}

private fun Context.getContentFileName(uri: Uri): String? = runCatching {
    contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        return@use cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME).let(cursor::getString)
    }
}.getOrNull()
```

Comment: Good answer, but on my opinion it's better to insert these funs (Context.getFileName and Context.getCursorContent) in a file with name 'Context', delete words object FileUtils and use it as extention, for example: val txtFileName = context.getFileName(uri)

Comment: @LumisD you can import these extensions in any file, your suggestion is correct but I just hate when methods are global. I want to see certain methods only if I import them and not always. And sometimes I prefer having same method names and different sources so I import the ones I need in the right place:)

Comment: You can import it this way: import com.example.FileUtils.getFileName
or just write context.getFileName(uri) and hit Alt+Enter and your IDE will do it for you:)

Answer (score 32):

Easiest ways to get file name:

```
val fileName = File(uri.path).name
// or
val fileName = uri.pathSegments.last()
```

If they don't give you the right name you should use:

```
fun Uri.getName(context: Context): String {
    val returnCursor = context.contentResolver.query(this, null, null, null, null)
    val nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
    returnCursor.moveToFirst()
    val fileName = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
    returnCursor.close()
    return fileName
}
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want it short this should work.

```
Uri uri= data.getData();
File file= new File(uri.getPath());
file.getName();
```

Comment: I am getting a name with file.getName() but its not actual name

Comment: My fileName is user.jpg but I am getting "6550" in response

Comment: It doesn't return actual file name. Actually it return last part of your resource url.

Comment: This does not work as a file! Mostly URIs have to be decoded by the MediaStore today. Reason why I and others are getting the numbers. Because those are the IDs of those files.

Comment: This was a response given 4 years ago.  Android is obviously changing every release.

Comment: then what should I do for getting the actual name of the file?

Answer (score 15):

The most condensed version:

```
public String getNameFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
}
```

Comment: do not forget to close cursor :)

Answer (score 11):

I use below code to get File Name & File Size from Uri in my project.

```
/**
 * Used to get file detail from uri.
 * <p>
 * 1. Used to get file detail (name & size) from uri.
 * 2. Getting file details from uri is different for different uri scheme,
 * 2.a. For "File Uri Scheme" - We will get file from uri & then get its details.
 * 2.b. For "Content Uri Scheme" - We will get the file details by querying content resolver.
 *
 * @param uri Uri.
 * @return file detail.
 */
public static FileDetail getFileDetailFromUri(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    FileDetail fileDetail = null;
    if (uri != null) {
        fileDetail = new FileDetail();
        // File Scheme.
        if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
            File file = new File(uri.getPath());
            fileDetail.fileName = file.getName();
            fileDetail.fileSize = file.length();
        }
        // Content Scheme.
        else if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
            Cursor returnCursor =
                    context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            if (returnCursor != null && returnCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
                fileDetail.fileName = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
                fileDetail.fileSize = returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex);
                returnCursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
    return fileDetail;
}

/**
 * File Detail.
 * <p>
 * 1. Model used to hold file details.
 */
public static class FileDetail {

    // fileSize.
    public String fileName;

    // fileSize in bytes.
    public long fileSize;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public FileDetail() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Helped solve my problem with loading file names from external or internal data! Very useful thank you!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to have the filename with extension I use this function to get it. 
It also works with google drive file picks

```
public static String getFileName(Uri uri) {
    String result;

    //if uri is content
    if (uri.getScheme() != null && uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        Cursor cursor = global.getInstance().context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                //local filesystem
                int index = cursor.getColumnIndex("_data");
                if(index == -1)
                    //google drive
                    index = cursor.getColumnIndex("_display_name");
                result = cursor.getString(index);
                if(result != null)
                    uri = Uri.parse(result);
                else
                    return null;
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    result = uri.getPath();

    //get filename + ext of path
    int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (cut != -1)
        result = result.substring(cut + 1);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helped me.

Comment: For me it was that leading underscore on the column name.

Answer (score 8):

My answer would be an overkill, but here is how you can get filename from 4  different uri types in android.

1. Content provider uri `[content://com.example.app/sample.png]`
2. File uri `[file://data/user/0/com.example.app/cache/sample.png]`
3. Resource uri `[android.resource://com.example.app/1234567890]` or `[android.resource://com.example.app/raw/sample]`
4. Http uri `[https://example.com/sample.png]`

```
fun Uri.name(context: Context): String {
    when (scheme) {
        ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE -> {
            return toFile().nameWithoutExtension
        }
        ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT -> {
            val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
                this,
                arrayOf(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME),
                null,
                null,
                null
            ) ?: throw Exception("Failed to obtain cursor from the content resolver")
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            if (cursor.count == 0) {
                throw Exception("The given Uri doesn't represent any file")
            }
            val displayNameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameColumnIndex)
            cursor.close()
            return displayName.substringBeforeLast(".")
        }
        ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE -> {
            // for uris like [android.resource://com.example.app/1234567890]
            var resourceId = lastPathSegment?.toIntOrNull()
            if (resourceId != null) {
                return context.resources.getResourceName(resourceId)
            }
            // for uris like [android.resource://com.example.app/raw/sample]
            val packageName = authority
            val resourceType = if (pathSegments.size >= 1) {
                pathSegments[0]
            } else {
                throw Exception("Resource type could not be found")
            }
            val resourceEntryName = if (pathSegments.size >= 2) {
                pathSegments[1]
            } else {
                throw Exception("Resource entry name could not be found")
            }
            resourceId = context.resources.getIdentifier(
                resourceEntryName,
                resourceType,
                packageName
            )
            return context.resources.getResourceName(resourceId)
        }
        else -> {
            // probably a http uri
            return toString().substringBeforeLast(".").substringAfterLast("/")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For most uses, the filename isn't that essential and some sane fallback could be used, so throwing exceptions may not be desirable.
Just returning a nullable `String?` would be better for a Kotlin-y solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
public String getFilename() 
{
/*  Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getData().getLastPathSegment();
    return name;*/
    Uri uri=getIntent().getData();
    String fileName = null;
    Context context=getApplicationContext();
    String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    if (scheme.equals("file")) {
        fileName = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    }
    else if (scheme.equals("content")) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE };
        Uri contentUri = null;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            fileName = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: this didn't work in my case , but Vasanth answer did.

Answer (score 2):

This actually worked for me:

```
private String uri2filename() {

    String ret;
    String scheme = uri.getScheme();

    if (scheme.equals("file")) {
        ret = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    }
    else if (scheme.equals("content")) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            ret = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this :

```
  private String displayName(Uri uri) {

             Cursor mCursor =
                     getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
             int indexedname = mCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
             mCursor.moveToFirst();
             String filename = mCursor.getString(indexedname);
             mCursor.close();
             return filename;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for a `Kotlin` answer especially an `extension` function, here is the way to go.

```
fun Uri.getOriginalFileName(context: Context): String? {
    return context.contentResolver.query(this, null, null, null, null)?.use {
        val nameColumnIndex = it.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
        it.moveToFirst()
        it.getString(nameColumnIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my utils method to achieve this. You can copy/paste and use it from anywhere.

```
public class FileUtils {

    /**
     * Return file name from Uri given.
     * @param context the context, cannot be null.
     * @param uri uri request for file name, cannot be null
     * @return the corresponding display name for file defined in uri or null if error occurs.
     */
    public String getNameFromURI(@NonNull Context context,  @NonNull Uri uri) {
        String result = null;
        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // error occurs
        }
        finally {
            if(c != null){
                c.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
...
}
```

And usage.

```
String fileName = FileUtils.getNameFromContentUri(context, myuri);
if(fileName != null){
    // do stuff
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
 Uri uri = result.getData().getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
 uri = Uri.parse(uri.getLastPathSegment());
 System.out.println(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

This prints the file name with extension

Comment: This will not work with all uris. For example, if I use a uri I received from Google Photos `content://com.google.../image%2Fjpeg/484274255` this will not return a valid file name with an extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
String Fpath = getPath(this, uri) ;
File file = new File(Fpath);
String filename = file.getName();
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit what your code does? This way your answer will be more useful for other users stumbling over this issue. Thanks

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work on marshmellow. It just outputs "audio and some number"

Answer (score 1):

My version of the answer is actually very similar to the @Stefan Haustein. I found the answer on Android Developer page [Retrieving File Information](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info.html); the information here is even more condensed on this specific topic than on [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) guide site. In the result from the query the column index containing file name is `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME`. None of other answers/solutions for column indexes worked for me. Below is the sample function:

```
 /**
 * @param uri uri of file.
 * @param contentResolver access to server app.
 * @return the name of the file.
 */
def extractFileName(uri: Uri, contentResolver: ContentResolver): Option[String] = {

    var fileName: Option[String] = None
    if (uri.getScheme.equals("file")) {

        fileName = Option(uri.getLastPathSegment)
    } else if (uri.getScheme.equals("content")) {

        var cursor: Cursor = null
        try {

            // Query the server app to get the file's display name and size.
            cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)

            // Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
            // move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data.
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                fileName = Option(cursor.getString(nameIndex))
            }

        } finally {

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close()
            }

        }

    }

    fileName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to convert your `URI` object to `URL` object, and then use `File` object to retrieve a file name:

```
try
    {
        URL videoUrl = uri.toURL();
        File tempFile = new File(videoUrl.getFile());
        String fileName = tempFile.getName();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
```

That's it, very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Stefan Haustein function for xamarin/c#:

```
public string GetFilenameFromURI(Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {
            string result = null;
            if (uri.Scheme == "content")
            {
                using (var cursor = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
                        {
                            result = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DisplayName));
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        cursor.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (result == null)
            {
                result = uri.Path;
                int cut = result.LastIndexOf('/');
                if (cut != -1)
                {
                    result = result.Substring(cut + 1);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Combination of all the answers

Here is what I have arrived at after a read of all the answers presented here as well what some Airgram has done in their SDKs - A utility that I have open sourced on Github:

https://github.com/mankum93/UriUtilsAndroid/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/androiduriutils

### Usage

As simple as calling, `UriUtils.getDisplayNameSize()`. It provides both the name and size of the content.

**Note:** Only works with a content:// Uri

Here is a glimpse on the code:

```
/**
 * References:
 * - https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=MLNO/airgram/airgram-master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/ir/hamzad/telegram/MediaController.java
 * - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568874/how-to-extract-the-file-name-from-uri-returned-from-intent-action-get-content
 *
 * @author Manish@bit.ly/2HjxA0C
 * Created on: 03-07-2020
 */
public final class UriUtils {


    public static final int CONTENT_SIZE_INVALID = -1;

    /**
     * @param context context
     * @param contentUri content Uri, i.e, of the scheme <code>content://</code>
     * @return The Display name and size for content. In case of non-determination, display name
     * would be null and content size would be {@link #CONTENT_SIZE_INVALID}
     */
    @NonNull
    public static DisplayNameAndSize getDisplayNameSize(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Uri contentUri){

        final String scheme = contentUri.getScheme();
        if(scheme == null || !scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)){
            throw new RuntimeException("Only scheme content:// is accepted");
        }

        final DisplayNameAndSize displayNameAndSize = new DisplayNameAndSize();
        displayNameAndSize.size = CONTENT_SIZE_INVALID;

        String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                // Try extracting content size

                int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
                if (sizeIndex != -1) {
                    displayNameAndSize.size = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex);
                }

                // Try extracting display name
                String name = null;

                // Strategy: The column name is NOT guaranteed to be indexed by DISPLAY_NAME
                // so, we try two methods
                int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                if (nameIndex != -1) {
                    name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                }

                if (nameIndex == -1 || name == null) {
                    nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    if (nameIndex != -1) {
                        name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                    }
                }
                displayNameAndSize.displayName = name;
            }
        }
        finally {
            if(cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

        // We tried querying the ContentResolver...didn't work out
        // Try extracting the last path segment
        if(displayNameAndSize.displayName == null){
            displayNameAndSize.displayName = contentUri.getLastPathSegment();
        }

        return displayNameAndSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Intent data = result.getData();
// check condition
if (data != null) {
    Uri sUri = data.getData();
    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(sUri, null, null, null, null);
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    String file_name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

我从开发者官网找到一些信息

I got some information from the developer's website

取得游标

```
val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(fileUri, null, null, null, null)
```

接着就可以获取名称和文件大小

```
val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
cursor.moveToFirst()
val fileName = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
val size = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)
```

别忘记关闭资源

Don't forget to close resources

[Retrieving file information](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info#kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

This will return the filename from Uri without file extension.

```
fun Uri.getFileName(): String? {
    return this.path?.let { path -> File(path).name }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67514042/8013212) I described a way to get the filename with the extension.

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information