# URI from Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT into File

Tags: android

1. Launch photo picker using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
2. Retrieve URI of selected item
3. Retrieve PATH of URI so that I can POST it to my webserver

   **Code to launch browse**

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   intent.setType("image/*");
   startActivityForResult(intent, BROWSE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
   ```

   **Code to retrieve selected image**

   ```
   if (RESULT_OK == resultCode &&
                BROWSE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
   Uri uri = data.getData();
   ```

   **Code to send to the webserver**

   ```
   File file = new File(uri.getPath());
   new FileSystemResourceFile(file);
   ```

I am currently able to retrieve the PATH from the URI no prob `/external/images/media/24` but for some weird reason file is always null, help please?

Comment: uri.getPath() is /external/images/media/24. This is file?

Comment: yes and i'm trying to pass that file to FileSystemResourceFile to no avail

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've done this method to convert `Uri` from `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to real path:

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Activity activity, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Which in turn converted into `File`:

```
Uri filePathFromActivity = (Uri) extras.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
filePathFromActivity = Uri.parse(FileUtil.getRealPathFromUri( (Activity) IntentActivity.this, filePathFromActivity));
File imageFile = new File(filePathFromActivity.getPath());
```

Comment: Activity.managedQuery is depreciated.  Use:      CursorLoader loader=new CursorLoader(activity, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
 instead

Comment: @Patrick It's very much not obvious to me HOW you would use a CursorLoader in this case. Or how to use it at all, frankly. The documentation leaves a lot to be desired. Since I can run this whole task in a thread, I'm going to just ignore your advice and use the deprecated managedQuery(). Because it's much more obvious how to make that work, especially since I need a synchronous result.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim to use the CursorLoader just call the loadInBackground() method. It will return a Cursor.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html#loadInBackground%28%29

Comment: filePathFromActivity  always null , how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a long time since the answer, but I faced the same wall and this is the solution I ended up with. The main benefit of this code is that avoids having parametrized (and hard-coded) all possible providers types and locations across all different android versions.

```
    val act = getActivity() as Activity
    object: AsyncTask<Uri, Void, File?>() {
        override fun doInBackground(uris: Array<Uri>): File? {
            if(act.isFinishing()) return null
            try {
                val dir = act.getCacheDir()
                val file = File.createTempFile("PREFIX", "SUFFIX", dir)
                val inputStream = act.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uris[0])
                val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
                        .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos)
                return file
            } catch(e: Exception) { e.printStackTrace() }
            return null
        }
        override fun onPostExecute(result: File?) {
            result?.let { doSomethingWithFile(it) }
        }
    }.execute(uri)
```

I put it wrapped inside of an AsyncTask for the purpose of leaving unblocked ui thread during bitmap compress. Please be aware that using `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG` means lossing alpha channel.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Pick any file using System File Picker:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.type = "*/*"
startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
```

onActivityResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val file = data?.data?.let {
            getFileFromUri(requireContext().contentResolver, uri, requireContext().cacheDir)
        }
    }
}
```

Get File:

```
private fun getFileFromUri(contentResolver: ContentResolver, uri: Uri, directory: File): File {
    val file =
        File.createTempFile("suffix", "prefix", directory)
    file.outputStream().use {
        contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.copyTo(it)
    }

    return file
}
```