# Android Intent ImageChooser Image Path

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using Android Intent Chooser to select a photo from gallery with following code.

```
ivAvatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Bir fotoğraf seçin ..."), 1);
        }
    });
```

After selection  using  the path I fill the imageview with following code :

Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

```
        imagepath = ImagePathUtil.getPath(getApplicationContext(), selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        ivAvatar.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        selectedU = selectedImageUri;

        File f = new File(String.valueOf(selectedU));

        if(f.exists())
        {
            int i = 1;

        }
```

Image can be viewed without any problems, but the File object I create afterwards File 's exists() method always return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning false because the file will be null. Please look at the below post for more details on how to get the real path from URI.

[URI from Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT into File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646246/uri-from-intent-action-get-content-into-file?lq=1)