# failure delivering Resultinfo

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
<!-- language: none -->    

    04-23 11:47:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(12396):
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.t4t.sp/com.t4t.sp.SignUpActivity}:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=111, result=-1, data=Intent { act=content://media/external/images/media/3809 (has extras) }} to activity {com.t4t.sp/com.t4t.sp.SignUpActivity}:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am not able to find out why the activity is not able to produce the result,what I want is I am launching an edit intent and after the editing I want to supply the uri to my onactivity result.

Edited :

Here is my code of on create method

```
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        mUsername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
        mPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        mImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        medit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        medit.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        mImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {




                               Intent choosePhotoIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);              choosePhotoIntent.setType("image/*");
                choosePhotoIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                choosePhotoIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
                choosePhotoIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
                choosePhotoIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                choosePhotoIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                choosePhotoIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
                startActivityForResult(choosePhotoIntent, PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST);








            }
        });    


`
```

here is my onactivity for result code where i am getting a null value for data as when i am trying to fetch the url its saying null pointer over there :

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("resultcode",Integer.toString(resultCode));
    Log.e("requestcode",Integer.toString(requestCode)); 
    String fileType = null;
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
    if(requestCode==PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST)


    {




        medit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mImageUri=data.getData();
        String imageUri=getRealPathFromURI(mImageUri);
        mImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri));
        }
```

@Mighter

Comment: Please show your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the error you are getting:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=111, result=-1, data=Intent { act=content://media/external/images/media/3809 (has extras) }} to activity {com.t4t.sp/com.t4t.sp.SignUpActivity}:`

You can see the `Intent` that is being passed as the `data` argument to `onActivityResult()`:

`data=Intent { act=content://media/external/images/media/3809 (has extras) }`

This `Intent` contains extras and an **ACTION**, but it contains no **DATA** field. This is why you are getting `null` when calling `data.getData()`.

The URL you are looking for is being returned in the **ACTION** (which is kinda stupid IMHO, but that's beside the point). You need to do this instead:

```
    String imageUri=data.getAction();
    mImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri));
```

Comment: Thanks alot i was not able to get what was going wrong,it worked for me now i am able to get the uri of the intended image which i was wanting.
@David

Comment: So I don't need to return in action in your opinion then what stupidity i am doing can you let me know actually i am newbie so not much know about it. 
@David Wasser

Comment: Well, if you are returning an URL it would make more sense to either return it in the "data" field of the `Intent` or simply as a String extra.

Answer (score 0):

in your return url class:

```
Activity act=this;
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
//Log.i("class2","uri: "+uri);
returnIntent.setData(uri);
//Log.i("class2","return: "+returnIntent.getData().toString());
act.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);  
act.finish();
```

in the calling class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//Log.i("class1","finish");
}
```

when you start the Editing class.

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,Editing.class);
//Log.i("class1","start");
this.startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

If your code is the same as mine then try adding the log comments to get a better idea of what the problem is.

Comment: No actually what i am trying to do is geeting the result back on the same activity in onactivity for result method. @theellipsis

Comment: [looks similar to this question then.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448856/android-camera-intent-how-to-get-full-sized-photo)
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);

Comment: Actually thats a differnt context in that its about taking images from camera but i am chosing it from gallery

Comment: try :
    String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
[src](http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/pick-file-using-intentactiongetcontent.html)

Comment: I keep on getting the same error
04-23 16:26:17.909: E/AndroidRuntime(2774): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=111, result=-1, data=Intent { act=content://media/external/images/media/3828 (has extras) }} to activity {com.t4t.sp/com.t4t.sp.SignUpActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: change if to 
    if(requestCode==PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST&&data!=null), just to check the error occurs inside there and is because data is null.

Comment: I changed it to the way u said but i keep on getting this error,whats the root cause i am still not able to get

Comment: what outputs do you get for these lines? 
    Log.e("resultcode",Integer.toString(resultCode));
    Log.e("requestcode",Integer.toString(requestCode));

Comment: put a log above this line medit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        something like Log.e("intent",data.toString());

Comment: I tried this and i am getting this message
04-23 17:36:14.479: E/intent(5347): Intent { act=content://media/external/images/media/4008 (has extras) }

Comment: [try one of these answers, it looks like you have to receive the url differently as it can be content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568874/how-to-extract-the-file-name-from-uri-returned-from-intent-action-get-content)