# Android: Get path of a text file from URI brings a weird path

Tags: android, uri

I want the user to select a text file so the app can read its content. in onActivityResult I have the following code:

```
Uri filePath = data.getData();
File file = new File(filePath.getPath());
```

filePath.getPath() brings this weird path: /document/**1EEB-0A13:**Download/filename.txt

I don't understand what is 1EEB-0A13:, I'm almost certain that without it, it would work. Needless to say that I get an exception that there is no such file or directory.

I saw a lot of examples on how to get the real path but they seemed to be related to images. I tried one of them but it threw an exception.

Comment: i don't have explanation but please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568874/how-to-extract-the-file-name-from-uri-returned-from-intent-action-get-content

Comment: You  should look at filePath.toString() and realise that it is not a file path but an uri with a content scheme. Use the content scheme instead of a file path.

Comment: `1EEB-0A13` is the USB identifier for your SD card. Put in a different card and see that this identifier changes.

Comment: `how to get the real path`. Dont try to do that anymore. Modern times now adays. Use the uri to open an InputStream is you want to read the content of the file.

Comment: @greenapps thanks for the tip, please add it as a solution so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at `filePath.toString()` and realise that it is not a file path but an uri with a content scheme. Use the content scheme instead of a file path.

`1EEB-0A13` is the USB identifier for your SD card. Put in a different card and see that this identifier changes.

`how to get the real path`. Dont try to do that anymore. Modern times now adays. Use the uri to open an InputStream is you want to read the content of the file

Answer (score 1):

> I want the user to select a text file so the app can read its content.

Unfortunately, you decided not to show the code for how you are doing this. I am going to assume that you are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, or perhaps `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Neither of those have much to do with files.

> filePath.getPath() brings this weird path: /document/**1EEB-0A13:**Download/filename.txt

`getPath()` only has meaning for a `Uri` with a `file` scheme. Yours has a `content` scheme, in which case the "path" is an opaque series of characters, having no meaning to you.

> I'm almost certain that without it, it would work

I'm almost certain that it will not. For starters, not every `Uri` that you get back from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` will look like that. The user may have any number of apps that respond to `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, and any number of `DocumentsProviders` that plug into the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` UI.

> I saw a lot of examples on how to get the real path but they seemed to be related to images.

And they are all bug-riddled pieces of junk.

Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.