# Get filename from google drive URI

Tags: android, google-drive-api, android-imageview, android-bitmap, google-drive-android-api

In my app, user can pick image from camera and Gallery to load into ImageView.

I am using following code to open relevant application to choose image:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

Problem is with the Google drive. If user select an image from Google Drive, I am getting URI like this: content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DHxtpLaMr66OMOzDOKTRZ-5ed7q7Szj7F7nC0IlxBnV8hx2P1%0A

I am able to generate Bitmap but unable to get file name.

```
 InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
               Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream(input);
```

I need to show File name which user has selected.

Please, help me to extract image name from google drive URI.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

> I am able to generate Bitmap but unable to get file name

There does not have to *be* a filename. Not every sequence of bytes has a filename. For example, this answer does not have a filename.

> Please help me to extract image name from google drive uri.

That is not strictly possible.

You could switch to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Then, wrap the resulting `Uri` in [a `DocumentFile` using `fromSingleUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#fromSingleUri(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)). Then, call `getName()` on the `DocumentFile`. This will be a "display name", something that the user should recognize. **It still may not be a filename**.

I cannot rule out the possibility that the Google Drive API has some means of getting a display name from a `Uri` that you get from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, though that would surprise me. It is also possible that your `Uri` from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` will work with `DocumentFile` — if you add `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` to your `Intent`, it would increase the odds that this works.

Comment: Checked in Kitkat, DocumentFile object is getting created but getName() method returning null. How can I get display name kitkat and below?

Comment: - check above comment

Comment: @RohanPatel: That may be a `DocumentFile` limitation. I have [a better version in this library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-document). Or, you can `query()` for the `OpenableColumns` yourself using a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark for the `fromSingleUri()` tip, does wonders on Google Drive files!

Answer (score 3):

Use the way provided and recommended by Google (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider):

```
Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
  String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can recommend you two ways:

First way is that name the file yourself and save it to another URI in phone.

And the second way, you can get filename from uri itself. See the answer below:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005243/6514270)