# Questions reagarding bitmap image and image storage

Tags: android, imageview, bitmapimage

I have the bitmap image that I got from my camera activity. Can someone please guide me as to how can I store this image in the gallery?

code:

In my button OnClickListener

```
    Intent campic=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(campic,cameradata );
```

In my onActivityResult

```
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
           Bundle bun=data.getExtras();
           bmp=(Bitmap)bun.get("data");
           SaveIamge(bmp);
           iveventpic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
```

Comment: [This link][1] is probably what you're looking for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560501/android-save-image-into-gallery

Comment: if you save to gallery it wont show up until the next time you turn your phone on uless you sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call this function to save bitmap in sdcard:

```
private void SaveIamge(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

By calling this line u have to store that image in the gallery:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

and Add permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: It worked :) But the gallery does not show the image immedietely. Is is that the gallery is refereshed after a fixed interval?

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp, title, desc);
```

As seen in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560501/android-save-image-into-gallery)