# Failed to save image from app assets folder to Gallery Folder in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, android-assets

I have written this code its saving image in specified folder name but i want to save this image in **Gallery/Specified FolderName/Image**.Can someone please help me .....
**CODE:**

```
saveImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            saveImage(getBitmapFromAsset("save_fatwa.jpg"),
                    "save_fatwa.jpg");
        }
    });


private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        if (istr.equals(null)) {
            Log.i("getBitmapFromAsset isStr", "" + istr);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager
                    .open("save_fatwa.jpg"));
        } else {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
}

private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, String imageName) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Jamia Binoria Images");
    myDir.mkdirs();

    // String fname = "save_fatwa.jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, imageName);
    if (file.exists()) {
        Log.i("file exists", "" + imageName);
        file.delete();
    } else {
        Log.i("file does not exists", "" + imageName);
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,out);
        // sendBroadcast(new Intent(
        // Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
        // Uri.parse("file://" +
        // Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here i have used another function to get images from Assets Folder.Please let me know what to add in this code to save it in Gallery/FolderName/Image

Comment: any stacktrace in the logcat?

Comment: Have you add write and read external storage permission to manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Add Permission to mainfest.xml file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here is a [link](http://rajareddypolam.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/android-saving-file-to-external-storage/) check this

Comment: yes i have added how can i make this code to create folder in gallery  and save images there right now its creating folder in Files

Comment: This link may help u http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12696/saving-to-external-public-directory/

Comment: can u please help me how to show alert to user after saving images successfully

Comment: use Toast to display the message after saving the image.

Comment: Use this code after saving.
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image save Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: i mean how can i ensure that either images have been saved or not

Comment: After saving the file in SD card,you can check whether the file exist or not if exist then show the toast "File saved" else file not save.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48130/discussion-between-user3233280-and-android-learner)