# Android: write photo files on SD Card that are viewable in the gallery

Tags: android, sd-card

I'm trying to found a way (compatible with android kitkat and next) to write photos on the SD Card and make them visible to the gallery app.

- If I use Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory , samsung devices return a path in internal memory (/storage/emulated/0/ ... )
- If I use Context.getExternalFilesDirs , there are two results : the first one on internal storage, and the second one on SD Card. Ok, I can write inside and the photo is on the SDCard. But I can't see it in the Galery app :'(

I have tried to write directly on /storage/externalSdCard/DCIM/ but of course I can't since I'm running kitkat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android - save image into gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560501/android-save-image-into-gallery)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_PICTURES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ok, I can write inside and the photo is on the SDCard. But I can't see it in the Galery app

First, when you are done writing to the file, call `flush()`, then `getFD().sync()`, then `close()`, all on your `FileOutputStream`.

Then, use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to get the newly-written file indexed by the `MediaStore`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the final solution 

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String [] {fDst.getAbsolutePath()} , null, null);

Answer (score 0):

```
void saveImage() {
        File filename;
        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

            new File(path + "/folder/subfolder").mkdirs();
            filename = new File(path + "/folder/subfolder/image.jpg");

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

            bitMapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filename.getAbsolutePath(), filename.getName(), filename.getName());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Saved in  " + filename, 1000).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage() worked. But then I deleted file from the galery and re-run my test code. And now it does'nt work anymore : I get a file not found exception whereas the file is present (I've checked this point 3 times)

Comment: surround this code with try catch(Filenotfoundexeption e)                                                                                                                               String path  make it global variable and on  oncreate activity          path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();                                 new File(path + "/folder/subfolder").mkdirs();