# Unable to save the picture in the directory created

Tags: android

I am taking a picture without using the camera preview. It takes the picture and shows the Toast but I am unable to save the picture in my Tab. How can I do this?

This code results in the following error

> Fatal Exception that "no activity found for intent"

```
package androidfeatures.countmyapp.com.takingpicturewithoutpreviewandsaving;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Button capture_image;
    private static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE =1 ;
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private Uri fileUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        capture_image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_image);
        capture_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                capture();
            }
        });
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(MainActivity.this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void capture() {
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Taken",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

                // start the image capture Intent

                //intent.putExtra("image_arr", data);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                camera.stopPreview();
                if (camera != null) {
                    camera.release();
                    mCamera = null;
                }
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("CameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        }/* else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        }*/else {
            return null;
        }
        //mediaFile.delete();
        return mediaFile;

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && data != null) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                //fileUri = data.getData();
                byte[] image = data.getExtras().getByteArray("data");
               // Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                        image, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } else {
                // Image capture failed, advise user
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        Log.e("Surface Changed", "format   ==   " + format + ",   width  ===  "
                + width + ", height   ===    " + height);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e("Surface Created", "");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e("Surface Destroyed", "");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your intent in onPictureTaken has no action, so Android cannot tell what you are trying to do. You probably need to manually save the data to a file, rather than trying to use an Intent to do it.

Comment: how can i manually save the data..please help

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560501/android-save-image-into-gallery) might help you.

Comment: i am not getting any help from this question please make some changes to my code if you can..

Comment: is there anybody to help me in this code?