# How to take screenshot of a layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gallery

I want to save my frame layout into gallery by taking the screen shot of the layout. This code works on a project(Name: Trial), but when I tried the same code on othe project(Name: Fg), It did not work. The photo is not being saved in the Gallery.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_background);




}
public Bitmap click(View view) {
    FrameLayout memecontentView =(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.my);
    View view1 = memecontentView;

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view1.getWidth(), view1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
    view1.draw(canvas);


    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myPath = new File(extr, getString(R.string.free_tiket)+".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b,
                "Screen", "screen");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;


}
```

}

Comment: is the photo created at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android?rq=1  or http://stackoverflow.com/a/8722494/794088

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you got the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Declared in your manifest?

Also if you want the entire view try this:

```
view1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view1.getDrawingCache());
```

Oh and this may save you some time:

```
private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Src: [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)