# Converting Layout XML files to Image

Tags: android-studio

I am currently creating a layout for an android application. Is there any way of converting the XML files I made into an Image file from android studio or just get the shot of the window in its full size?

Comment: please explain your question

Comment: Is there a function in android studio where I can screenshot my layout?

Comment: are you talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444410/how-to-take-screenshot-of-a-layout-in-android or https://github.com/nisrulz/screenshott ?

Comment: No. I only have layouts, no classes/activities yet. Now, is there any way to get those layouts into images? Snipping tool/printscreen doesn't show the full size of the layouts.

Comment: you can use the Preview button in the upper right corner to add a preview window next to the XML code

Comment: @undefinedBehavior I need to export them as images.