# Saving an image into my Gallery

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an Android application in Android studio where the user can take a photo and save it into a new folder in their gallery. Currently the application takes the pictures fine but doesn't save the image into the new "SOC" folder in my gallery. I'm not getting any errors and I have no idea why it's not saving the image. Any help would be appreciated.

My code is as fallows

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
public void onClickbtnCamera(View v)
{
    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/SOC","QR_"+timeStamp+ ".png"));
    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 1);
}



   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {

            //Check for succesful result code
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                //Show your Toast when the result is a success.
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Picture is saved in your SOC gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 100, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how you implement on activity for result ?

Comment: I do I added my activity there

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: I tried my code on another phone and it worked but for some reason it doesn't work on my phone. Not sure why this is

Answer (score 0):

I think you must manually add your new photo Uri to Media Content Provider.
take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722494/4486007)

Comment: I think this could have been a comment!

Comment: You shouldn't answer with a link and without any could snippet!!

Answer (score 0):

Call this method in your Activity for result

```
 protected void addPhotoToGallery() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(getCurrentPhotoPath());
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

you should save the photo path before launching the intent and then getCurrentPhotoPath() must get that path