# I am unable to send image from recyclerview.adapter to another activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder ,int position) {
    Glide.with(c)
            .load(images.get(position))
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(holder.img);
    holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{
                String fileName = "bitmap.png";
                FileOutputStream stream = c.openFileOutput(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Intent showBigPicture = new Intent(c,showBigPicture.class);
                Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images.get(position));
                bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
                stream.close();
                bitmapImage.recycle();
                showBigPicture.putExtra("image",fileName);
                c.startActivity(showBigPicture);

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

this is showing in logCat " Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{e22d977 V.ED..C. ...P.... 0,0-540,890 #7f0b0061 app:id/img}: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

Comment: It looks like you're just passing file name to the next Activity. Is there a reason you're creating the Bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36624927/4971152) on saving Bitmap images. I believe the reason you're getting a FileNotFoundException is because you're providing the URI to a file that doesn't exist yet to the decodeFile function that's quite possibly a URL from what I can tell. In short, to save a bitmap:

1. Create a new `File(filename)`
2. Decode file using getName on the File from step 1
3. Create `FileOutputStream` from `File`
4. Compress the bitmap image into the `FileOutputStream`

From what I can surmise from your question, it looks as though you're showing a images in a RecyclerView and when an image is clicked, you want to open another activity which shows a version of the full image. If that's close to your use-case, and you're using Glide, I would recommend taking advantage of its built-in automatic caching feature to reduce network calls instead of manually saving the file.

By default, disk and memory-based caching is enabled in Glide as long as the same filename, path, or URL are used to obtain the image on each `Glide.load(...)`. If you'd like to manipulate how the caching occurs, use the `DiskCacheStrategy` enum to control that every time you load the image:

```
Glide.with(c)
        .load(images.get(position))
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)  # Will cache the source downloaded image before any transformations are applied
        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .into(holder.img);
```

If you still want to save the file for other reasons, use a SimpleTarget instead of loading directly into your ImageView like so:

```
Glide.with(c)
        .load(images.get(position))
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)  # Will cache the source downloaded image before any transformations are applied
        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .asBitmap()
        .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                        holder.img.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
                        saveImage(bitmap); # This being an encapsulation of the steps outlined earlier
                    }
  });
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I want to show a full-size image in another activity but I can't figure out how to use   .diskCacheStrategy to do that.

Comment: You just have to use that line on the Glide loader in both your preview activity and in the full-size image activity. Best way to test if proper caching is used would be to clear all app data, load the preview activity to ensure image is downloaded, then turn off any network connection and try loading the full-sized activity. The image in the full-size activity should still load from the full-sized image saved in the cache