# Can not read image with BitmapFactory.decodeFile

Tags: android, fileinputstream, bitmapfactory

Bitmap size is only 49 KB.

I have permissions in my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But the following code returns ***null***, it can not read the image from file.

```
Im = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath) // <== file: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.App1/files/MyImages/MyImg.png"
```

***BitmapFactory.decodeFile*** returns null.

I searched and tried suggestions with Filestream as follows:

```
try {
    val dest = File(fullPath, fileName)  // dest: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.App1/files/MyImages/MyImage.png"
    var fis: FileInputStream
    fis = FileInputStream(dest)      // <= Jumps to catch section from this line
    Img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis)
}
catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e("File could not be found", e.message)    
}
return Img
```

But, the cursor jumps to the catch section from the line fis = FileInputStream(dest) when I debug it. It gives this error:

```
e=java.io.FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory)
```

When I put this ***try-catch*** block into an "if" statement, like this;

```
val file = File(fullPath, fileName)
if (file.exists()){
      // the above try-catch block is here
 }
```

then the condition "***file.exists()***" is *NOT* true (But I can see in the device, the file exists. It is in the same path taken with the "***dest***" parameter, whose value is given above as you see)

I saved the PNG file with the codes at [how to save bitmap to android gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624756/how-to-save-bitmap-to-android-gallery) given by Bao Lei. Those codes are below:

```
/// @param folderName can be your app's name
    private fun saveImage(bitmap: Bitmap, context: Context, folderName: String) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            val values = contentValues()
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/" + folderName)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, true)
            // RELATIVE_PATH and IS_PENDING are introduced in API 29.

            val uri: Uri? = context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
            if (uri != null) {
                saveImageToStream(bitmap, context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri))
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, false)
                context.contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null)
            }
        } else {
            val directory = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + separator + folderName)
            // getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated in API 29

            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs()
            }
            val fileName = System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".png"
            val file = File(directory, fileName)
            saveImageToStream(bitmap, FileOutputStream(file))
            if (file.absolutePath != null) {
                val values = contentValues()
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, folderName)
                // .DATA is deprecated in API 29
                context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun contentValues() : ContentValues {
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        return values
    }

    private fun saveImageToStream(bitmap: Bitmap, outputStream: OutputStream?) {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream)
                outputStream.close()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

The if statement; ***if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29)*** is *not* true. Therefore, only remaining ***else*** section is runing. In this ***else*** section, I removed this code;

```
    if (file.absolutePath != null) {
        val values = contentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, file.absolutePath)
        // .DATA is deprecated in API 29
        context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
    }
```

Because, it causes this error:

```
Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=14668, uid=10271 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

So, the function ***saveImageToStream*** in the above code saves the image.

Now, the problem about the reading the PNG is

```
 e=java.io.FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory)
```

although the PNG does exist. How to solve this problem ?

The code ***fis = FileInputStream(dest)*** is in the DidtodayActivity.kt file. And, this activity file is defined in the Manifest file as;

```
<activity android:name=".DidtodayActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mystudio.otherlab.MainActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".secondActivity" />
<activity android:name=".loginActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Is there any problem in the Manifest file?

Why the error (file could not be found) does occur although the path is correct and the PNG file does exist? I hope someone can help

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208576/discussion-on-question-by-member-can-not-read-image-with-bitmapfactory-decodefil).

Comment: So, path is correct. File does exist. Why does the error (File could not found) occur?

Answer (score 0):

What this give you out

```java
try {
   // Img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath) //<= returns null

    val dest = File(fullPath, fileName)  // dest: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.App1/files/MyImages/MyImage.png"

    System.out.println("DEST IS: " + dest);  // <= Check this in Logcat

    var fis: FileInputStream
    fis = FileInputStream(dest)      // <= Jumps to catch section from this line
    Img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis)
}
catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e("File could be find", e.message)    
}
```

Comment: It jumps to catch section from this line ==> fis = FileInputStream(dest).  Thanks, e.message should include "NOT" (I edited the question). How to solve this problem?