# How do I save a picture to the default images folder on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camerax

I have this function that saves an image to the `Internal storage/Android/media` folder on your phone:

```
fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
    val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
        File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
    return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
        mediaDir else filesDir
}
```

I want to change the code so that I can save the image in the default `Images` folder that way when the user opens their Gallery app, they'll easily be able to see it. How do I do that?

Comment: Saving to Gallery depends on the platform version, 29 (Android 10) introducing some [new ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57265702/192373).

Comment: @AlexCohn What do I pass in as the parameters? My `getOutputDirectory` doesn't require any parameters but the link you sent me as methods that require parameters.

Comment: The main difference is that you cannot simply calculate the full path and use file API to create this file. You need a **ContentResolver** to explicitly register your picture for Gallery.