# Unable to store image taken to Gallery

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using Galaxy S6 running Marshmallow. I followed this documentation https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html and am able to take photos in my app. However, I cannot get the photos to be added to Gallery.

Here is my code to do so:

```
    Log.d(TAG, "sending broadcast to add image to gallery.");
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

    Log.d(TAG, "scheme: " + contentUri.getScheme().equals("file"));
    Log.d(TAG, "action: " + Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));
    Log.d(TAG, "path: " + contentUri.getPath());
    Log.d(TAG, "ExternalStorageDirectory: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
```

Once executed I see the following in the logs:

06-19 03:09:20.121 8803-8803/com.my.package.name D/TakePicActivity: sending broadcast to add image to gallery.
06-19 03:09:20.121 8803-8803/com.my.package.name D/TakePicActivity: contentUri path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package.name/files/Pictures/JPEG_20160619_030913_-155289398.jpg
06-19 03:09:20.131 8803-8803/com.my.package.name D/TakePicActivity: scheme: true
06-19 03:09:20.131 8803-8803/com.my.package.name D/TakePicActivity: action: true
06-19 03:09:20.131 8803-8803/com.my.package.name D/TakePicActivity: path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package.name/files/Pictures/JPEG_20160619_030913_-155289398.jpg
06-19 03:09:20.131 8803-8803/com.my.package.name D/TakePicActivity: ExternalStorageDirectory: /storage/emulated/0

I am able to `adb shell` and `ls -l /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package.name/files/Pictures/JPEG_20160619_030913_-155289398.jpg` and see `-rw-rw---- u0_a229  sdcard_rw  5004392 2016-06-19 03:09 JPEG_20160619_030913_-155289398.jpg`

My AndroidManifest.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my.package.name">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activities.SpringboardActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.my.app.name.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>

    <receiver android:name=".MediaScannerBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
</manifest>
```

And I have this BroadcastReceiver but see nothing from it in the logcat after I try to add a pic that was just taken thru the app to gallery:

```
public class MediaScannerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED)) {
        Log.d("MediaScanner", "ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED received");
    }
    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED)) {
        Log.d("MediaScanner", "ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED received");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer here (use insertImage): http://stackoverflow.com/a/37534444/5852261

Comment: Thanks. i am still hoping to resolve the issue with Broadcast with Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE