# Image in gallery is saved with wrong orientation

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

To take a photo I'm using the camera installed on the device.
The photo is saved inside the gallery but is **always saved horizontally**.

 How do I fix it?

**This is the intent when click on the button "add photo":**

```
 private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = null;
                photoURI = galleryAddPic();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
```

**This is the method `createImageFile()`:**

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        imageFileName = "JPG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
```

**In the end, this is the method `galleryAddPic()`:**

```
private Uri galleryAddPic(){
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        return contentUri;
    }
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

After inserting the photo into the gallery, I can rotate the image as I want it.
But in the gallery the image is not rotated well.
So I would like to save the image in the gallery with the right orientation. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Collect information about orientation of picture from (EXIF meta data) because picture orientation depends on the camera built into device .
this code reads information from EXIF data and rotate image accordingly

```
BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bounds);

BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, opts);
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file);
String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) :  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;

int rotationAngle = 0;
if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) rotationAngle = 90;
if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) rotationAngle = 180;
if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) rotationAngle = 270;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle, (float) bm.getWidth() / 2, (float) bm.getHeight() / 2);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bounds.outWidth, bounds.outHeight, matrix, true);
```

Information from **EXIF**:

```
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                     ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

switch(orientation) {

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

    default:
        break;
}
```

rotate bitmap method

```
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                               matrix, true);
}
```

[SAVE Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560501/android-save-image-into-gallery) to Gallery

hope it helps !!

Comment: I already do this in a method to show the image in a imageview.and function, but I need to rotate the bitmapt and then store it in the gallery

Comment: Yes, but before the methos addGalleryPic, Bitmap in sull if i call decodeBitmap(path). When take a photo, how do retrive the bitmap?

Comment: Don't you already get Bitmap from here ?                                         
             protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }  
    }