# How do I take a picture on Android app, and save photo to gallery in internal storage? (Not SD Card)

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I have my app so I have the ability to open the camera and take a picture, the app then shows me a preview of the photo just taken, and when I press 'OK', it is gone. I want to be able to save the image I have taken to my internal storage on my phone, (and possibly have a function so I can access my gallery and preview it later on). I have searched everywhere but all the help I am getting is to store it on an SD card, whereas I want to use my phones built in storage. Thank you

My code so far:

```
Button butCamera;
ImageView imageView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    butCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butCamera);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);



    butCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

});
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

Comment: Internal storage means app-private storage in android dev. Shared storage is external storage, and can be the SD card. But not necessarily

Comment: "android save picture to internal storage" would make a really good web search. It sure would.

Comment: what is your butCamera button for? is it the button for saving the image?

Comment: Take a look at this post, it should have what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560501/android-save-image-into-gallery

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is quite complex,
an i'm not sure you could use this common storage method to achieve it

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

But have a loot at this post, it should have what you require

[android - save image into gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560501/android-save-image-into-gallery)

Answer (score -1):

To store the Image to Internal storage of the device, you will have to do something like this.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyFile.jpg");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```