# How to download image and save it in local storage using Xamarin-Forms.?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to download an image and store it in specific folder in local storage.

I am using this to download image:

```
var imageData = await AzureStorage.GetFileAsync(ContainerType.Image, uploadedFilename);
var img = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageData));
```

Comment: What have you tried and how, exactly, is that not working? Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - without that we probably won't be able to help you.

Comment: I dont know the way. What should I do for that.... Can you please give me any idea or any link

Comment: I have a Android link, But how i can achieve in xamarin.forms https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560501/android-save-image-into-gallery

Comment: Start by reading up on file handling in Xamarin.Forms. That should give you a good starting point. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=vswin

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Create a FileService interface**

in your Shared Code, create a new Interface, for instance, called IFileService.cs

```
 public interface IFileService
 {
      void SavePicture(string name, Stream data, string location="temp");
 }
```

**Implementation Android**

In your android project, create a new class called "Fileservice.cs".

Make sure it derives from your interface created before and decorate it with the dependency information:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileService))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class FileService : IFileService
    {
        public void SavePicture(string name, Stream data, string location = "temp")
        {
            var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            documentsPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Orders", location);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsPath);

            string filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, name);

            byte[] bArray = new byte[data.Length];
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath , FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (data)
                {
                    data.Read(bArray, 0, (int)data.Length);
                }
                int length = bArray.Length;
                fs.Write(bArray, 0, length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Implementation iOS**
The implementation for iOS is basically the same:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileService))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class FileService: IFileService
    {
        public void SavePicture(string name, Stream data, string location = "temp")
        {
            var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            documentsPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Orders", location);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsPath);

            string filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, name);

            byte[] bArray = new byte[data.Length];
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath , FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (data)
                {
                    data.Read(bArray, 0, (int)data.Length);
                }
                int length = bArray.Length;
                fs.Write(bArray, 0, length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to save your file, in your shared code, you call

```
DependencyService.Get<IFileService>().SavePicture("ImageName.jpg", imageData, "imagesFolder");
```

and should be good to go.

Comment: i was trying to edit the awnser, but can't edit only 1 char, in the shared code, you get the Interface on the DependencyService, not the project implementation class

DependencyService.Get<IFileService>().SavePicture("ImageName.jpg", imageData, "imagesFolder");

Comment: Should it automatically create a folder named "temp" or where does it save the image? I ran the code, and it compiled, but I can't find the image that I saved

Comment: Looks like this could all be done from the shared project, couldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

```
public void DownloadImage(string URL)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[e.Result.Length];
        bytes=e.Result; // get the downloaded data
        string documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;

        var partedURL = URL.Split('/');
        string localFilename = partedURL[partedURL.Length-1];
        string localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
        File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, bytes); // writes to local storage
        Application.Current.MainPage.IsBusy = false;
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Download", "Download Finished", "OK");
        MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Forms.Context,new string[] { localPath }, null, null);
    };
    var url = new Uri(URL);
    webClient.DownloadDataAsync(url);
}
```

Here you have to use dependency service from xamarin forms PCL to call this method from android project.This will store your image to public folder. Will edit this if  i get time to make a demo with iOS also.

Comment: How would it be for the implementation with iOS

Answer (score 2):

I really liked Karan's approach.

I've made a sort of combination of them both and I wanted to share them here. Worked pretty well actually.

```
public String DownloadImage(Uri URL)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    string folderPath   = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Images", "temp");
    string fileName     = URL.ToString().Split('/').Last();
    string filePath     = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, e.Result);
    };

    webClient.DownloadDataAsync(URL);

    return filePath;
}
```