# How do I download a file on both Android X and iOS that is publicly available, using Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, download, android-10.0

Looking at this issue [xamarin/Essentials#1322](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1322), how do I download a file on both Android ( versions 6-10, Api 23-29 ) and iOS ( version 13.1+ ) that is publicly available (share-able to other apps, such as Microsoft Word). I don't need to give write access to the other apps, just read-only is ok if it must be restricted.

I get the following exception:

```
    [Bug] Android.OS.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/user/0/{AppBundleName}/cache/file.doc exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

With the following code.

```
    public static string GetCacheDataPath( string fileName ) => Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fileName);
    public static FileInfo SaveFile( string filename, Uri link )
    {
        using var client = new WebClient();
        string path = GetCacheDataPath(filename);
        DebugTools.PrintMessage(path);
        client.DownloadFile(link, path);
        return new FileInfo(path);
    }
    public async Task Test(Uri link)
    {
        LocalFile path = await SaveFile("file.doc", link).ConfigureAwait(true);
        var url = new Uri($"ms-word://{path.FullName}", UriKind.Absolute);
        await Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher.OpenAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(true);
    }
```

With this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51040802/9530917), I created a FileService interface and it works with local private files but I am unable to share the files. Starting with Android Q (10 / Api 29), the following is deprecated.

```
    string path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;  // deprecated
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.doc' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
```

I haven't found any way yet to get a public path for Android 10 with Xamarin.Forms. I've looked at the [Android Docs for Content providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers) but it's in Java, and I can't get it working in C# yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can solve the FileUriExposedException in the usual way with using FileProvider.

Comment: Under Android Q external storage is no longer accessable. But you can edit the manifest file to get access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a [Solution](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1322#issuecomment-658985681)

> **Found a fix**
>
> For Android
>
> ```
> public Task<System.IO.FileInfo> DownloadFile( Uri link, string fileName )
> {
>   if ( link is null )
>       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(link));
>
>   using System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
>
>   // MainActivity is the class that loads the application.
>   // MainActivity.Instance is a property that you set "Instance = this;" inside of OnCreate.
>   Java.IO.File root = MainActivity.Instance.GetExternalFilesDir(MediaStore.Downloads.ContentType);
>   string path     = Path.Combine(root.AbsolutePath, fileName);
>
>   client.DownloadFile(link, path);
>
>   return Task.FromResult(new System.IO.FileInfo(path));
> } 
> public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
> {
>   internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }
>   
>   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>   {
>       ...
>       Instance = this;
>       ...
>   }
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> For iOS
>
> ```
> public Task<System.IO.FileInfo> DownloadFile( Uri link, string fileName )
> {
>   if ( link is null )
>       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(link));
>
>   using System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
>   string path = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fileName)
>   client.DownloadFile(link, path);
>
>   return Task.FromResult(new System.IO.FileInfo(path));
> } 
> public async Task Share()
> {
>   // back in shared project, choose a file name and pass the link.
>   System.IO.FileInfo info = await DependencyService.Get<IDownload>().DownloadFile(new Uri("<enter site>", "file.doc").ConfigureAwait(true);
>   
>   ShareFile shareFile = new ShareFile(info.FullName, "doc"); // enter the file type / extension.
>   var request = new ShareFileRequest("Choose the App to open the file", shareFile);
>   await Xamarin.Essentials.Share.RequestAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(true);
> }
> ```
>
> Note that for iOS, due to Apple's infinite wisdom... I cannot share the file directly with another app as I can on Android. Sandboxing is good for security but in this case, how they implemented it, it limits options. Both Applications must be pre-registered / pre-allocated in an "App Group" to share files directly. See this [Article](https://codemilltech.com/sending-files-to-a-xamarin-forms-app-part-1-ios/) and the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for more information.