# SyncFusion SignaturePad saving in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm trying to work out how to download a signature from the SFSignaturePad component from SyncFusion. Is there a guide anywhere on how to do this, Syncfusion doesn't offer any answers in it's documentation and I can't find any examples anywhere.

Edit; aiming to download as an image

Thanks

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/160385/saving-result-of-signature-pad

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed your query "SyncFusion SignaturePad saving in Xamarin Forms" in SfSignaturePad. We can save the signature by calling the Save method of SfSignaturePad control. We have created a sample based on your requirement and please get the sample [link](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SfSignaturePad_ImageSource-462500232).

Please refer to download the image using the below link, [How to download image and save it in local storage using Xamarin-Forms.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51038251/how-to-download-image-and-save-it-in-local-storage-using-xamarin-forms)