# Newly created image not showing in gallery

Tags: android, image-gallery

I am creating an image (some sort of copy of another gallery image) using API, and the image is not being shown in the gallery.

I know the new file is there because I can see it using adb shell, and it's placed in the same folder as the original one.

I may be wrong, but I recall reading about specifying the type of file you are creating at creation time, but I cannot find it anymore.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you updating your MediaStore? Thats surely the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you create the file, then try manually notifying the Media Scanner about the file, as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815005/614231).

Comment: great! I used the SingleMediaScanner class and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the file/folder just fire this broadcast.This invokes the Gallery to scan all the media files

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,<file-path>));
```