# How do i save an image in external storage gallery in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-image

I'm trying to write an image file into the public gallery folder in a specific directory but I keep getting an error that I can't open the file because its a directory.

What I have so far is the following

```
//set the file path
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + directory;

    File outputFile = new File(path,"testing.png");


    outputFile.mkdirs();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Where directory is the application name. So all the photos saved by the application will go into that folder/directory, but I keep getting the error

```
/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/appname/testing.png: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

Even if I don't try to put it in a directory and cast the variable path as a File like

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

I don't get the error however the photo is still not showing up in the gallery.

***Answer
The problem was that when I ran this code originally it created a DIRECTORY named testing.png because I failed to create the directory before creating the file IN the directory. So the solution is to make the directory first then write into it with a separate file like so

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + File.separator + directory;

//directory is a static string variable defined in the class

            //make a file with the directory
    File outputDir = new File(path);

            //create dir if not there
    if (!outputDir.exists()) {
         outputDir.mkdir();

    }

            //make another file with the full path AND the image this time, resized is a static string
    File outputFile = new File(path+File.separator+resized);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Note you may need to go into your storage and manually delete the directory if you made the same mistake i did to begin with

Comment: sometimes gallery need to be refreshed. Go to your folder path through ddms and check if your new file is created or not.

Comment: Yeah I did that multiple times withno luck

Comment: For scanning your new file see this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile/5815005#5815005

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage/7887114#7887114

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to write into a directory instead of file.
try this

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + directory;   
File outputDir= new File(path);   
outputDir.mkdirs();   
File newFile = new File(path + File.separator + "test.png");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);   
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Comment: What had happened is at one point my code wrote the full path as a directory. So i had a directory called "testing.png" than I tried to write the bitmap into that directory. This method works

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, only little changes needs as follows,

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + directory;

    // First Create Directory
    File outputFile = new File(path);
    outputFile.mkdirs();

    // Now Create File
    outputFile = new File(path,"testing.png");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Also don't forget to give WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting this error while working on Android Emulator; you need to enable SD Card storage on the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/FolderName");
        if(!myDir.exists())
            myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".png";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is now deprecated and you should use

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

Comment: I had no idea and would have spent time meaninglessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this way :

```
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,  new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg"));`
```

**`Path :  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + file name`**