# Updating and removing files on MediaScanner when connected to a computer

Tags: android, usb

I'm writing an application that creates, updates and deletes files on the "SD-card". If I run this on a Nexus 7 I need to notify the media scanner service that files are created/deleted/updated. I have implemented SingleMediaScanner class from this thread: [Android How to use MediaScannerConnection scanFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile) . It works great if the device is not connected to a computer. If I connect it I immediately see the latest files.

But it doesn't work well if the device is connected to a computer via USB. Creating files works fine. But updating files from my application doesn't work. If I do this and copy it to my computer I still get the version that was existing when I connected the device to my computer (disconnect and connect the device solves this). If I copy files from my computer to the devices, I immediately could use the new file in my application. If I delete a file, it still looks like it existing on my computer but the size is 0 bytes. This is also solved by disconnect and connect the device.

I'm really confused by this. Is this by design? Is there anything I could do to solve this?

Comment: "Is this by design?" -- of the MTP client, perhaps. What is the computer's OS?

Comment: I have tried on both Windows 7 and 8, same result on both systems. This blog is great by the way: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html :-)

Comment: The MTP client is probably caching data and not realizing that it needs refreshing automatically. I am not aware of anything you can do about it, other than to advise users to refresh manually (e.g., via the File Explorer menu). And I'm glad you found that blog post useful!

Comment: Ok, thanks for a quick explanation :-). I will try this on another OS when I can. Refreshing manually doesn't solves the problem, I have already tried that. I have also tried to restart explorer, and sign in on a different user account on my computers with the same result. I have noticed that if I rename a file it will be in sync again, that maybe one dirty workaround. But in my case it's most likely not a problem (it's really unlikely that some modifies a file when it's connected to a computer), I just don't like things I don't understand :-).