# Windows explorer does not refresh when using android media scanner

Tags: java, android

In my application I want to rename and delete folders or files on the external storage directory.
For this I use a modified version of the mediascanner from this question:
[Android How to use MediaScannerConnection scanFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile)

This seems to work fine because for example the android app "AndroZip" shows the renamed folder. But in windows explorer the folder still has the old name and a new file with no extension appears with the new folder name.
I've tryed to disconnect the usb-cable, refresh the windows explorer or use other implementations of mediascanner like the broadcast intent. But the only thing that worked is restarting my android device.

Media Scanner:

```
public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

private MediaScannerConnection mediaScannerConnection;
private String path;

SingleMediaScanner(Context context, String path) {
    this.path = path;
    mediaScannerConnection = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
    mediaScannerConnection.connect();
}

@Override
public void onMediaScannerConnected()
{   
    File folder = new File(path);
    if (folder.isDirectory())
    {
        String[] filesInFolder = folder.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < filesInFolder.length; i++)
        {
            mediaScannerConnection.scanFile(path + "/" + filesInFolder[i], null);
        }
        mediaScannerConnection.scanFile(path, null);
    }
    else
    {
        mediaScannerConnection.scanFile(path, null);
    }
}

@Override
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    mediaScannerConnection.disconnect();
}
```

}

Rename method

```
public void renameFormular(String oldName, String newName)
{
    File oldFolderName = new File(FORMULARS + "/" + oldName);
    File newFolderName = new File(FORMULARS + "/" + newName);

    oldFolderName.renameTo(newFolderName);

    String[] values = newFolderName.list();

    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        String oldFormularFileName = FORMULARS + "/" + newFolderName + "/" + values[i];
        String newFormularFileName = oldFormularFileName.replace(oldName, newName);
        File oldFormularFile = new File(oldFormularFileName);
        File renamedFormularFile = new File(newFormularFileName);
        oldFormularFile.renameTo(renamedFormularFile);
    }

    new FolderMediaScanner(context, FORMULARS);
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu. MediaScannerConnection doesn't seem to play well the USB connection. Before KitKat, ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED was doing the trick well but since it's not supported any more in 4.4, I'm stuck. ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE doesn't help either in Kitkat regarding this issue.