# Captured image not appearing in gallery

Tags: android

I'm using the camera intent to captured images. But it's not showing when I check in on the gallery..

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

Intent intent_cam = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                    
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "App Photos");

Intent mediaScan = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {       

imagesFolder.mkdirs();          
File image = new File(imagesFolder, "App_" + timeStamp + ".png");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);         
intent_cam.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);    
mediaScan.setData(uriSavedImage);
getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScan);
startActivityForResult(intent_cam, 0);           
}

else if (imagesFolder.exists()) {

File image = new File(imagesFolder, "App_" + timeStamp + ".png");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
intent_cam.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
mediaScan.setData(uriSavedImage);
getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScan);
startActivityForResult(intent_cam, 0);    

}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

And is it true that the sendBroadcast no longer works in API 19. (4.4)? [Android How to use MediaScannerConnection scanFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile)

Comment: did you try to do the media scan send broadcast in onActivityResult()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the scan request before the picture has been captured. Recall that `startActivityForResult()` is asynchronous. Put your `sendBroadcast()` call in `onActivityResult()`, which will be triggered when the camera activity returns control to you.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem. Does it still works in API 19. (4.4)?

Comment: @luwionline: If you mean the broadcast, then yes, that works on Android 4.4.

Comment: And this one doesn't? sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

Comment: @luwionline: Correct. That was never an appropriate way to get your file indexed, and as of Android 4.2 it can only be broadcast by system apps.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in all android versions:

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.getPath()}, new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);