# Image not show in gallery

Tags: android, android-camera, android-file

I launch default **camera using intent** and store those camera images in **external storage** using below path:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                   + File.separator + fileName);
```

But it does not show in gallery. The issue comes in nexus 4,7 and moto G devices with OS 4.4.2

I try with

```
mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri
                .parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

But It not work

Comment: You need to call the MediaScanner, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5815005/2065418

Answer (score 1):

You will have to refresh the media scanner cache, try this:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(yourFile)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the device to scan the new media file. Try with this snippet:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
        this, new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better make a folder in the camera default folder and put your data in it. Check if a file with the name of ".nomedia" is not in that folder.