# Android, media scan doesn't generate thumbnails?

Tags: android, thumbnails, media

I have image files which don't have thumbnails. (imported from my external carmera using NFC)

I want to create thumbnails for my image picker view. (has to be fast)

At this moment, I'm not even sure "MEDIA SCAN" means "generating thumbnail" or what.
I tried to scan file using `mMediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mPath, null);`

`onScanCompleted` gets called and I try to get thumbnail using the following two version of functions.

I get null thumbnailPath for both functions, I don't get why..

```
    private String getThumbnailPath(long imageId) {
        ContentResolver cr = this.mContext.getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(cr, imageId, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
        try {
            if (c.moveToNext()) {
                int dataId = c.getColumnIndex( Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
                String strThumPath = c.getString(dataId);
                Log.i("ScanTest", "strThumPath = " + strThumPath );
                return strThumPath;
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) c.close();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String getThumbnailPath2( long imageId ){
        // http://wikicloud.blogspot.kr/2010/10/scanfile.html
        ContentResolver cr = this.mContext.getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "= ?" , new String[]{String.valueOf(imageId)}, null);
        try {
            if (c.moveToNext()) {
                int dataId = c.getColumnIndex( Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
                String strThumPath = c.getString(dataId);
                Log.i("ScanTest", "strThumPath = " + strThumPath );
                return strThumPath;
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) c.close();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

-- edit --

Here's how I try to get thumbnails.

1. first create a mapping from image-id to thumbnail-path.

   protected Map getThumbnailPathFromDB() {
       Map result = new HashMap();
       Cursor thumbCursor = null;
       thumbCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null, null);

   ```
   if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
           String path = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                   .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
           long imageId = thumbCursor.getLong(thumbCursor
                   .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));
           result.put(new Long(imageId), path);
       } while(thumbCursor.moveToNext());
   }

   thumbCursor.close();

   return result;
   ```
2. next I iterate all images and try to find thumbnails from the mapping I created above

   ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
   Cursor cursor = cr.query(
               Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, Images.ImageColumns.DATE_MODIFIED + " DESC");

   //thumbnailPathList is the mapping I created above, imageId is the id of image obtained from the cursor
   String thumbnailPath = thumbnailPathList.get(new Long(imageId));
   // thumbnailPath are occasionally null here!,

I tested my code on about 10 devices.
They all have images which I can't find thumbnails for.

Comment: `I have image files which don't have thumbnails`. You forgot to tell how you know that. Because they do not show up in Gallery app? You first have to find out who normally generates thumbnails on your device. Where are the thumbnails stored on a device? Please explain all here. Give a good context for your problem. `I want to create thumbnails for my image picker view.` Unclear if your app has to do that or an extern app. `long imageId` From where did you get that id?

Comment: Further name your Android version. And try on different devices/versions. Googling a bit i found many issues about thumbnails. It seems that the Gallery app is responsible for it. I just found 37599 thumbnails in a pretty new device. I had generated/downloaded a lot of images on it (no media scanner used)and they appeared all in the Gallery. That was not what i wanted and put some .nomedia files. The thumbnails are still there but the Gallery does not show those images any more. On kitkat.

Comment: I usually throw away thumbnails on devices. Sometimes they are contained in one big file. In no time all is back.