# Windows doesn't refresh files on Android device SD card

Tags: android

I'm developing an app. The app reads and writes files on SD card. But I have got some inconvinience. If the app writes the file on SD card I want to see it via Windows 7x64 file manager (any file manager: Explorer or Total Commander). The files are not shown until I reconnect the device (directly pull out and insert a wire to USB port). The files are shown as is in any file manager on Android. The device - Samsung Galaxy S3
Is it possible to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile (this, new String[] {file.toString()}, null, null);
```

Comment: Where I have to write this code? Directly after writing the files in the app?

Comment: Yes, after creating file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Anyway using your help I've found more complicated solutions. But your is the simplest. Here the link for future generations of programmers:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile

Comment: How to update deleted files? If I open the folder with deleted files the Explore in windows at first time shows this (deleted) files, then Explorer crashes:)

Comment: Hm... never thought about that.. I found one solution that might help you but I had no chance to test it so try to implement this in your project and let see. Here is the link http://pastebin.com/eN36uinC

Comment: The link above( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile ) I read %%sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));%% doesn't work for newest Android versions (>4.4)