# How to show images in gallery when you have added image in internal memory

Tags: android, android-file

I have added image in internal memory using code

```
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.blue_500);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("file.jpg",MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,80,fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
```

But Image not showing in gallery

Comment: are you using emulator ?

Comment: nope physical device

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile/5815005#5815005

Comment: Try turning your device off and then on again. This will make the media scanner run, so that it picks up your newly created image file.

Answer (score 0):

This is code work for me

```
 File file = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Note that this does not work on Android versions above 4.4 (KitKat).

Comment: This code work fine in lollipop but for brodcasting but for saving image to memory there is code difference