# Unable to display newly added media inside Gallery folder in Android

Tags: android

I am able to successfully record the audio and play it back. The file is being stored in the SD and has a filePath like so: `/storage/emulated/0/20160516_104008`. The problem is that I want the user to be able to access it via the gallery widget.

I researched this problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile) post recommended using `MediaScannerConnection` API, which I have implemented as follows:

```
     MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(_reactContext,
                  new String[] { audioFileName }, null,
                  new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
              public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
              }
        });
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
private boolean prepareAudioRecorder() {
        audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        audioFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        audioFileName += "/" + timeStamp;
        audioRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFileName);
        audioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            audioRecorder.prepare();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed");
            return false;
        }           
    }


public void stopAudioRecording(final Promise promise) {

        if (audioRecorderPromise != null) {
            audioFile = new File(audioFileName);
            releaseAudioRecorder();
            storeFile();
            promise.resolve("finished recording");
        } else {
            promise.resolve("not recording");
        }

private void releaseAudioRecorder() {
        if (audioRecorder != null) {
            audioRecorder.stop();
            audioRecorder.release();
             audioRecorder = null;
            if (audioRecorderPromise != null) {
                // audioRecorderPromise.resolve(Uri.fromFile(audioFile).toString());
                audioRecorderPromise.resolve(audioFileName);
                audioRecorderPromise = null;
            }   
        }       
    }

private void storeFile() {

        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, audioFileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audioFileName);
        ContentResolver cr =  _reactContext.getContentResolver();
        cr.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri newUri = cr.insert(base, values);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);         
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(audioFile));
        _reactContext.sendBroadcast(intent);        
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not provide the file name but the **absolute path**

Refer [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29)

**Update** Better use [MediaScannerConnectionClient:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient.html)

```
private MediaScannerConnectionClient mediaScannerConnectionClient = new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mediaScannerConnection.scanFile("pathToFile/someName.extension", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        if(path.equals("pathToFile/someName.extension"))
            mediaScannerConnection.disconnect();
    }
};
MediaScannerConnection mediaScannerConnection = new MediaScannerConnection(context, mediaScannerConnectionClient).connect();
```

Comment: `audioFilename` is defined as `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();` , and concatenated with a timeStamp. Is that not the absolute path?

Comment: It should be audioFile.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work: No errors were thrown, I was still able to play the file, but not able to see it in gallery

Comment: How you call scanFile? Try instead of intent call MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(audioFilename, null)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Try to use MediaScannerConnectionClient