# Android copied file does not show in Windows file explorer

Tags: android, file, copy

My problem is about making a copy of a file on an Android mobile.

Whichever Java method I use below, the file copy is created on the Android mobile.

I can see it, on the mobile, via the menu `Storage & USB -> Explore`.

But I cannot see it from a PC to which the mobile is connected via USB.

Note that I did not forget to activate the option `USB for file transfer -> Use USB for File transfers`.

To be more precise, on the (Windows) PC, and after I activate that option on the mobile, a file explorer opens up (on the PC) and I cannot see the file just created (on the mobile).

I cannot see it either via programming using the C++ API `PortableDeviceApi`.

Now, if I reboot the Android mobile and activate the option mentioned above, then I can see the file in a file explorer on the PC.

Do you know that problem?
Can you help me solve it?

The Android version is `6.0.1`.

Java methods used to make a copy of a file:

```
public static void makeACopyOfAFile(String s_srcFilePath, String s_destFilePath)
throws IOException
{
File srcFile = null;
File destFile = null;

        srcFile  = new File(s_srcFilePath);
        destFile = new File(s_destFilePath);

        FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, destFile);
}

public static void makeACopyOfAFile(String s_srcFilePath, String s_destFilePath)
throws IOException
{
File         srcFile = null;
File         destFile = null;
InputStream  inputStream = null;
OutputStream outputStream = null;
int          n_len = -1;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        srcFile  = new File(s_srcFilePath);
        destFile = new File(s_destFilePath);

        inputStream = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

        while((n_len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0)
        {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, n_len);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
}
```

====================================================

## EDIT_1

From that thread:
[Android How to use MediaScannerConnection scanFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile)

I added the code:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(currentActivity,
          new String[] { s_destFilePath }, null,
          new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
          Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
          Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
      }
 });
```

And it solved my problem.

Comment: Reboot your device and you can see them after a few minutes.

Comment: But... You did not tell to which location you copied the files. Please tell as not all locations will be told to the pc by the mtp protocoll.

Comment: `Now, if I reboot the Android mobile ` So you already know. You could have put that in the subject. And also right away in your post.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for your help. I edited my post because I found a solution. BR.