# Android - Why my saved image is not appearing in the default gallery of my phone?

Tags: android, image, save, storage, internal

I am trying to save an image from my application to the default gallery of my phone. The code below works perfectly if I have a SD card on the phone. The image saved appears in the phone's gallery and everything, as expected:

```
private Uri saveMediaEntry(File f, String title, String description, int orientation,      Location loc) {

    ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
    v.put(Images.Media.TITLE, title);
    v.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title);
    v.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);

    v.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, orientation);

    String nameFile = f.getName();
    File parent = f.getParentFile() ;
    String path = parent.toString().toLowerCase() ;
    String nameParent = parent.getName().toLowerCase() ;
    v.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, path.hashCode());
    v.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, nameParent);
    v.put(Images.Media.SIZE,f.length()) ;

    if( nameFile.toLowerCase().contains(".png") ){
        v.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");

    }else if( nameFile.toLowerCase().contains(".jpg") || 
              nameFile.toLowerCase().contains(".jpeg") ){
         v.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

    }else{
        v.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    }

    String imagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
    v.put("_data", imagePath) ;
    ContentResolver c = getContentResolver() ;

    Uri uriOfSucessfulySavedImage = null;
    uriOfSucessfulySavedImage = c.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, v);

    return uriOfSucessfulySavedImage;
  }
```

However, if I try to save the same image into the internal storage (for when the phone does not have a SD card), the image does not appear in the phone's gallery! To try to do that, I only change one line from the above code:

```
uriOfSucessfulySavedImage = c.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, v);
```

The interesting thing about this, however, is that the variable `uriOfSucessfulySavedImage` is not null (it returns  `content://media/internal/images/media/x`, where 'x' is a number). So, the image is being saved somewhere in the internal storage of the phone, but it is not getting displayed in the phone gallery's as when I use `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.

Does anybody have any clue what is going on? How can I save an image into the internal storage of the phone *and have that image in the phone's gallery*?

### Update

I forgot one important information. The File "f" in the parameters of the method *"saveMediaEntry"* is coming from this other method for when the SD card is mounted (that is, for the first code):

```
public static File getCacheDirectory(String desiredNameOfTheDirectory){

File fileCacheDir = null;

    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) ){

        fileCacheDir = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), desiredNameOfTheDirectory );
   }


    if(!fileCacheDir.exists()){
        fileCacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    return fileCacheDir;
}
```

and from the following code for when the SD card **is not** founded:

```
public static File getCacheDirectory(String desiredNameOfTheDirectory, Context   context){

    File fileCacheDir = null;

        fileCacheDir = context.getCacheDir();

    if(!fileCacheDir.exists()){
        fileCacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    return fileCacheDir;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image, saved to sdcard, doesn't appear in Android's Gallery app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170214/image-saved-to-sdcard-doesnt-appear-in-androids-gallery-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I believe you need to run the Media Scanner to scan the internal storage directory so that the gallery can see your newly saved image. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815005/1055373) here.

Comment: Thank you Henry. I will try that out.

Comment: I have just restarted my phone. All the images that I had saved in the internal storage before are now being shown in the gallery! So, it definitely has something to do with this Media Scanner you posted. Thanks! I will write some code later on to scan the media and post the solution.

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I have just used the SingleMediaScanner class of that post you referenced. Thanks a lot Henry!

Answer (score 8):

Another easy way to do it. Add this after saving your file.

```
File imageFile = ...
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { imageFile.getPath() }, new String[] { "image/jpeg" }, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Copy Past this Function in your Activity

```
private void scanner(String path) {

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(FrameActivity.this,
                new String[] { path }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "Finished scanning " + path);
                    }
                });
    }
```

And then add this Line where you save your image

```
scanner(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Worked like champ

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Write down this line once image stored in gallery.

```
File file = ..... // Save file

context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                        Uri.parse("file://"
                                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            } else {
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                        Uri.parse("file://"
                                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            }
```