# how to save camera images in diffrent folder

Tags: android, camera, gallery

this is my source code which give two option when click on browse button take picture from gallery or by take using camera  i want to create new folder called"myfolder" and allpicture which i capture by camera is save on that folder not mobile default gallery folder how i do that
??

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {
 private long rowID; 
 private EditText nameEt;
 private EditText capEt;
 private EditText codeEt;
 private EditText Donedate;
 private EditText Notes;
 private EditText Person;
 private  ImageView imageView1;
public  static Bitmap yourSelectedImage = null;
public static byte[] blob = null;
private final int CAMERA_PICTURE = 1;
private final int GALLERY_PICTURE = 2;
private Intent pictureActionIntent = null;
//public static        byte[] blob = new byte[2048];

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

      nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Address);
      capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Stage);
      codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Dueby);

      Donedate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Donedate);

      Notes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Notes);
      Person = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Person);

      imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      Button Browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Browse);
      Browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {               
        //      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        //      intent.setType("image/*");
         //     startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                startDialog();
            }
        });        

      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

      if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
         capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
         codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));  
         Donedate.setText(extras.getString("Location"));  
         Notes.setText(extras.getString("Notes")); 
         Person.setText(extras.getString("Person")); 
         }

      Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
             if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
             {
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                   new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                   {
                      @Override
                      protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                      {
                         saveContact();
                         return null;
                      }

                      @Override
                      protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                      {
                         finish();
                      }
                   }; 

                saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
             }

             else
             {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new  
 AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                alert.show();
             }
          } 
     });
   }

   private void saveContact() 
   {

//     byte[] blob = new byte[2048];

       ByteArrayOutputStream outStr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       yourSelectedImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStr);
        blob = outStr.toByteArray();

      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

      if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
      {
          dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                  capEt.getText().toString(),
                  codeEt.getText().toString(),
                  Donedate.getText().toString(),
                  Notes.getText().toString(),
                  Person.getText().toString()
                  ,blob
                  );
      }
      else
      {
         dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
            nameEt.getText().toString(),
            capEt.getText().toString(), 
            codeEt.getText().toString(), 
            Donedate.getText().toString(),
         Notes.getText().toString(),
          Person.getText().toString()
          , blob
         );
      }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  
    imageReturnedIntent) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

       if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE) {
            Uri uri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            if (uri != null) {
                // User had pick an image.
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]  
     {  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
                File photos = new File(imageFilePath);
                yourSelectedImage = decodeFile(photos);
                yourSelectedImage =  
    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourSelectedImage, 150, 150, true);
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                cursor.close();
            }
            else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No Image is selected.",  
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PICTURE) {
            if (imageReturnedIntent.getExtras() != null) {
                // here is the image from camera
                yourSelectedImage = (Bitmap)  
  imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            }
        }
    }
   private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < 
 REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale++;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null,  
   o2);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void startDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myAlertDialog.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
        myAlertDialog.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");

        myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new 
  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                pictureActionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,  
  null);
                pictureActionIntent.setType("image/*");
                pictureActionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, GALLERY_PICTURE);
            }
        });

        myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera", new  
  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                pictureActionIntent = new  
  Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, CAMERA_PICTURE);
            }
        });
        myAlertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ::

```
 private void SelectPhotoFromCamera() 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "/DCIM" + ".jpg");

           if(file.isDirectory()) 
           {
                 //DO SOMETHING
           }                   
           else
           {
                  //DO SOMETHING
           }   
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE_CAMERA);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post, it have the similar problem. You need to use Media scanner.
[Android - Why my saved image is not appearing in the default gallery of my phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552014/android-why-my-saved-image-is-not-appearing-in-the-default-gallery-of-my-phone)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;


public class ImageSaver {
    private String TAG = "ImageSaver";
    private Context context;
    private String FILENAME_LEADER = "bijintokei";
    private String DOWNLOAD_FOLDER = "download";
    private String STORAGE_DESTINATION = "/sdcard";
    private CompressFormat COMPRESS_FORMAT = CompressFormat.JPEG;

    /**
     * Return file extension
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private String getFileExtention() {
        String result = "bmp";
        if (COMPRESS_FORMAT.equals(CompressFormat.JPEG)) {
            result = "jpg";
        }
        if (COMPRESS_FORMAT.equals(CompressFormat.PNG)) {
            result = "png";
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public ImageSaver(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Return appropriate file path for saving
     * 
     * @param hhmm
     * @return File path
     */
    public String getFilePath4Saving(String hhmm) {
        String fileName = "", destination = this.getDefaultLocation(), filePath = "";
        int i = 0;
        File file;
        do {
            fileName = getMixedFileName(hhmm, i++);
            filePath = String.format("%s/%s", destination, fileName);
            file = new File(filePath);
        } while (file.exists());
        Log.d(TAG, "File path for saving: " + filePath);
        return filePath;

    }

    /**
     * Return a mixed file name from: - FILENAME_LEADER - Specified time - Order
     * number
     * 
     * @param hhmm
     * @param i
     * @return
     */
    private String getMixedFileName(String hhmm, int i) {
        String fileName = String.format("%s%s", FILENAME_LEADER, hhmm);
        String extension = getFileExtention();
        String result = String.format("%s.%s", fileName, extension);
        if (i > 0) {
            result = String.format("%s-%d.%s", fileName, i, extension);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Make sure Download folder is exists in the specified path
     */
    private boolean MakeSureFolderIsExists(String path, String folder) {
        File file = new File(path + "/" + folder);
        boolean result = true;
        if (!file.exists()) {
            result = file.mkdir();
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Create folder " + path + "/" + folder + ": "
                            + Boolean.toString(result));
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Return default location for saving image
     * 
     * @return By default return external storage
     */
    private String getDefaultLocation() {
        String result = this.STORAGE_DESTINATION;
        if (MakeSureFolderIsExists(result, DOWNLOAD_FOLDER)) {
            result = result + "/" + DOWNLOAD_FOLDER;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Save bitmap for hhmm minute to default destination
     * 
     * @param bitmap
     * @param hhmm
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap, String hhmm) throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Saving image: " + hhmm);
        String filePath = getFilePath4Saving(hhmm);
        File fo = new File(filePath);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fo);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        requestMediaScannerRefesh();
    }

    /**
     * Require Media Scanner refresh
     */
    private void requestMediaScannerRefesh() {
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri
                .parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
    }
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int screenHeight,
            int screenWidth){
        Bitmap b = null;
        try {

            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
            fis.close();

            int scale = 1;
            if (o.outHeight > screenHeight || o.outWidth > screenWidth) {
                scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(screenHeight / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
            }

            //Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: look at private void requestMediaScannerRefesh()  at the end