# Why can't some images be displayed on ImageView (Android)?

Tags: android, image, imageview, gallery

When I pick an image from my gallery, screenshots are shown but some images taken from camera aren't shown.

To be more specific, images taken using the system Camera app can't be shown while the ones taken using Camera360 can.

I wonder if there's any problem with my code. If there isn't, maybe it's because of my phone?

Thanks in advance. Sorry, my English isn't very good.

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

private String selectedImagePath;
private ImageView img;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_image);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                            SELECT_PICTURE);
                }
            });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            Drawable image;
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver()
                        .openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
                image = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, "file///"
                        + selectedImagePath.toString());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
            img.setImageDrawable(null);
            img.setImageDrawable(image);

        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170214/image-saved-to-sdcard-doesnt-appear-in-androids-gallery-app

Comment: Thanks JaKoZo but I still don't know how I'm supposed to fix it, sorry. Could you please show me?

Comment: wait :). will code some

Comment: why ur code works for me fine ? i have all my pictures

Comment: I have all my images too when I browse the Gallery but the ones taken from the Camera can't be shown on the ImageView.

Comment: what show logcat when u try to show them?

Comment: I print the path to the console, and the path is always shown whether the image is shown or not.
Seems like it's my phone that has problem, not my code.

Comment: then u know how what to do. check this on atnoher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I found the problem. My image is too large. Updated code with several improvements below:

```
private static Context context;

private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 3;

private String selectedImagePath;
private static String imageFilePath;
private static String videoFilePath;
private Uri fileUri;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Button btnGallery, btnCamera;

private Intent selectPictureIntent;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_image);

    context = this;

    btnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);

    btnGallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            Log.d("bitmap", selectedImageUri.getScheme());
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                // Selected image is local image
                Bitmap b = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),
                        selectedImagePath).getBitmap();
                int i = (int) (b.getHeight() * (512.0 / b.getWidth()));
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 512, i, true);
            } else {
                // Selected image is Picasa image
                loadPicasaImageFromGallery(selectedImageUri);
            }
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            addImageToGallery(imageFilePath, context);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            addVideoToGallery(videoFilePath, context);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the video capture
        } else {
            // Video capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver()
            .openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor
            .getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    } else
        return uri.getPath();
}

private void loadPicasaImageFromGallery(final Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA, MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        if (columnIndex != -1) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                // NEW THREAD BECAUSE NETWORK REQUEST WILL BE MADE THAT WILL
                // BE A LONG PROCESS & BLOCK UI
                // IF CALLED IN UI THREAD
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Bitmap bm = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                                .getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                        int i = (int) (bm.getHeight() * (512.0 / bm
                                .getWidth()));
                        bitmap = Bitmap
                                .createScaledBitmap(bm, 512, i, true);
                        // THIS IS THE BITMAP IMAGE WE ARE LOOKING FOR
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "MappyDiary");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("MappyDiary", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        imageFilePath = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"
                + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        mediaFile = new File(imageFilePath);
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        videoFilePath = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_"
                + timeStamp + ".mp4";
        mediaFile = new File(videoFilePath);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath,
        final Context context) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values);
}

public static void addVideoToGallery(final String filePath,
        final Context context) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.Button01:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        selectPictureIntent = Intent
                .createChooser(intent, "Select Picture");
        startActivityForResult(selectPictureIntent, SELECT_PICTURE);
        break;

    case R.id.Button02:
        // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling
        // application
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent2.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent2, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```