# Why the downloaded video from an android app not showing in the Gallery?

Tags: android, video

In my application, I have downloaded a video from the web and save it in the device's Internal storage. I can see the video file in the folder where I stored the video using the File Explorer app. But the gallery app in my mobile doesn't list the video from saved from my app. The gallery app lists the video I have downloaded from other apps like WhatsApp. What is the reason?

To see the video saved from my application in the gallery app, whether I need to set any permission in my app?

Comment: You better look for the answer at the sister site http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: You have to send signal to your Gallery to notify you have added a file. You can see multiple answers under this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170214/image-saved-to-sdcard-doesnt-appear-in-androids-gallery-app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add below line after you save the video file -

**For api < 14**

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

**for api >= 14**

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this, 
new String[] { Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() }, 
null, 
new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

              Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
              Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Madhan: Most Welcome :)

Comment: its not working for downloaded videos in removable sdcard package directory :(

Comment: @do01: try replacing "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" with the path where the video is stored.

Comment: removable sdcard dir is like:
/storage/1825-374/Android/data/com.example/files/my_video.mp4
and this is not shown in gallery at all :(

Comment: @do01: try "/storage/1825-374/Android/data/com.example/files/" instead of "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()".

Comment: @kevz : It not working, videos in app package directory cant be introduced to gallery! and we cant save videos in other directory of removable sdcard due to new android security rules