# Image Saved In Phone Storage Instead of SD Card and Also not Showing in Phone Gallery Why?

Tags: android, imageview, android-external-storage, save-image, android-internal-storage

I am having an application containing different images using `ImageView` and `ViewPager`. I want to save the current image shown through `ImageView` in `SD Storage`. But it always saved in `Phone Storage` successfully.
I want to save the image in `SD Card` and also saved image not showing in `Gallery` Why? Kindly help me out in this issue:

---

```
public void SaveIamge() {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/Cute_Baby_Images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        int currentImagePos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        Drawable drawable = viewPager.getResources().getDrawable(images[currentImagePos]);
        Bitmap finalBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

        if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sucessfully Save Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String) to create your file.

Comment: Kindly update my code, I did not understand the link.

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.getExternalDirectory()` returns phone storage. To get location of SD card, check [Find an external SD card location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5694933/5137352)

To make the images appear in gallery, you should let the media scanner scan the file using `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()`
Check [Image, saved to sdcard, doesn't appear in Android's Gallery app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2170214/5137352)

Comment: Kindly tell me what is the function for getting external storage(SD Card)?

Comment: I cannot understand the link.. Can you modify my code, I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function called `getDirectory()`

```
private static File getDirectory(String variableName, String... paths) {
    String path = System.getenv(variableName);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
        if (path.contains(":")) {
            for (String _path : path.split(":")) {
                File file = new File(_path);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    return file;
                }
            }
        } else {
            File file = new File(path);
            if (file.exists()) {
                return file;
            }
        }
    }
    if (paths != null && paths.length > 0) {
        for (String _path : paths) {
            File file = new File(_path);
            if (file.exists()) {
                return file;
            }
        }
    }

    //If any there is no SECONDARY STORAGE are detected return INTERENAL STORAGE
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
}
```

Change your code to

```
public void SaveIamge() {

    String root = getDirectory("SECONDARY_STORAGE").getAbsolutePath();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Cute_Baby_Images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    int currentImagePos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    Drawable drawable = viewPager.getResources().getDrawable(images[currentImagePos]);
    Bitmap finalBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sucessfully Save Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + root)));
}
```

I have added a `broadcast` to notify the `MediaScanner` to re-scan the filesystem for new files. This will fix the problem of images are not showing in the gallery.

Comment: There is no change in Application. Images are again saved in internal storage not external storage, kindly help me out to save images in external storage,, your code only shows images in gallery.

Comment: @AndroidLearner541 Paste the permissions you are using

Comment: @AndroidLearner541 Check the edited code its working properly for me

Comment: . <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

Comment: These are the permissions