# Android, Pick Image

Tags: android, android-image

Is there some possible way of picking images from picture folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you call the gallery intent and expect a result with `onActivityForResult`

Have a look here:

[How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android)

Further searching in SO yields this, a complete solution:

[Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)