# Allowing the User to choose a picture from the pictures folder

Tags: android

I am trying to write code that will allow the user to choose a picture from the pictures folder and send that picture to the internet. I am new to Android so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You first need to start an Activity which asks the user to pick a picture. You next need to handle the result of that choice.

1: CHOOSE PICTURE

```
Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK, Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URL);
startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, REQUEST_CHOOSE_IMAGE);
```

2: Handle the result of the Activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHOOSE_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // send picture to Internet
        }
    }
}
```

How exactly you send the picture is a completely separate question.

Comment: Thanks for that Shawn. Going to try it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done any Android programming but this looks very useful: [OpenIntents (2010)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209004809/http://www.openintents.org/en/node/159), file picker that can be incorporated into an app.

The [original link](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/159) is no longer available. But I've managed to find it from the [2010 Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209004809/http://www.openintents.org/en/node/159)

Comment: Broken link for http://www.openintents.org/en/node/159

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically/2636538#2636538).