# How can I limit a user to only picking photos from Android's MediaStore?

Tags: android, video, photo, mediastore

I want users to be able to choose a photo from their media library but don't want them to be able to choose a video. I'm having trouble limiting them to only choosing a photo. When I open the gallery app using

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
```

then they are able to choose both photos and videos. Is there a way to limit them to only choosing photos?

Comment: this post says its impossible without mimes but he doesnt quote documentation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991464/retrieving-only-images-from-gallery-when-firing-android-image-chooser-intent    look here as well though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that you need to also set a mime type to "image/*" using `Intent.setType(String type)`.

**UPDATE:** Looks like the proper way to set Uri and mime type at once is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "image/*");
```

**UPDATE 2:** This is because when we set mime type or data uri separatelly look what happens (taken from `Intent` sources):

```
public Intent setType(String type) {
    mData = null;
    mType = type;
    return this;
}

public Intent setData(Uri data) {
    mData = data;
    mType = null;
    return this;
}
```

At least this is true on API 2.2.

Comment: Interesting... It sounds like you are saying that you must set the data and type at the same time. Is that true?

Comment: I don't think this is true. I set them separately and it works fine.

Comment: @lowellk: Please check the "UPDATE 2" section in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [`ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) instead of `ACTION_PICK`. It allows you to set a the MIME type you want without having to specify a URI at all.