# How to show images stored on an SD card in an Activity with ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-gallery

I have images on the SD card and I want to show these images in an `Activity` with a `ViewPager`.

On horizontal scroll the image should change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this methode you can retrive your picture from SDcard in a drwable object

```
public Drawable getImageFromSdCard(String imageName) {
    Drawable d = null;
    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + "/YourSubDirectory/";
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + "/" + imageName
                + ".png");
        d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return d;

}
```

and then just call this Drawable in your ViewPager.

G.Luck

Comment: @WasimAkram I am looking for same, quite new to android. How can I call this in myviewpager. I am successfully retrieving images from drawable folder, but unable to get images from SD card.

Answer (score 1):

use this: [Retrieving only images from gallery when firing android image chooser intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991464/retrieving-only-images-from-gallery-when-firing-android-image-chooser-intent) to get image from gallery.

And use this to show it horizontally: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

You need to club both these codes together.

Comment: Thanks Shree but i have viewpager not gallery.