# How to open the image in the Android's default gallery

Tags: android, image-processing, android-gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open phones gallery through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016000/how-to-open-phones-gallery-through-code)

I have outputted a image in my app. Can I call the default Android's gallery to display the image instead of using ImageView to view the image.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I want to use the default Image Viewer in the android system. Since some function of the Viewer I would want to use. Can skip go into the gallery and go in the default Image Viewer

Answer (score 2):

try this for open gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to display the image in gallery using this code..

```
Intent intentquick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentquick.setDataAndType(<full path to image to be displayed>,"image/*");

intentquick.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intentquick);
```